# looking for selective latex command replacement methods

Tags: macros

I have a [perl script for generating wordpress](https://github.com/peeterjoot/physicsplay/blob/master/bin/tex2blog) (or physicsforums or wikipedia) style latex markup from standalone latex files, but it has grown into a bit of a monstrosity and has also recently met it's match, so I'm looking for options.  My script has support for many of the simple commands I use, such as:

```
\newcommand{\lr}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\Ba}[0]{\mathbf{a}}
\newcommand{\Bb}[0]{\mathbf{b}}
\newcommand{\acap}[0]{\hat{\Ba}}
\newcommand{\bcap}[0]{\hat{\Bb}}
\newcommand{\ccap}[0]{\hat{\Bc}}
\newcommand{\inv}[1]{\frac{1}{#1}}
\newcommand{\cross}[0]{\times}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\lvert{#1}\rvert}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\lVert{#1}\rVert}
...
```

but all these are hardcoded in the perl, and not based on the .sty file that I've stuffed these into (i.e. brutally ugly and non-extendable way of doing things).

I was hoping that there is something that could do just simple \newcommand replacement, ideally, given a file that is also \include'd or \usepackage'd and eliminate it from the latex text, replacing all the commands it contained.

I know of and have tried a few other methods for this sort of task, such as:

- Luca's [wordpress to latex](http://lucatrevisan.wordpress.com/latex-to-wordpress/).
- I found GPP referenced in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45961/preprocessor-for-latex), but attempting to use 'gpp -T' seemed to have no effect other than incorrectly stripping out a few @ symbols.  I'm guessing that 'latex style' for this program still requires manual alteration of the latex commands to use some sort of special syntax.
- In https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/3181/15 was a note to try \tracingmacros1.  Trying that I found the output was huge, and even after filtering it was huge:

  $ grep --binary-files=text -e '->' latexStdout.txt > q
  $ wc -l q
  6148361 q
  This also didn't give any indication where each of the macros came from and would be hard to use for a more selective replacement.  The trace package was referenced in a comment as having better output than plain \tracemacros1, but I found what it produced pretty incomprehensible.
- The [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144322/15) points out a [de-macro package](http://ctan.org/pkg/de-macro), but if I try that I get a python error that I don't know how to deal with:

  File "./de-macro", line 643, in scan_numargs
      raise "%s must be argument number after %s" % (numargs, name)
  TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not str

I see [hints that there isn't a latex grammar available](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4201/is-there-a-bnf-grammar-of-the-tex-language) that could be used to write a more robust standalone latex to latex preprocessor.  In other questions where people asked for latex preprocessors, there were suggestions to use \listfiles, which is nice but not helpful for selective replacement.

Conceptually, I would think this would be an ideal job for latex itself, since it already knows how to do the parsing.  I'd imagine that for somebody who knew the latex backend, it might not be too hard to create a new output mode that was latex-text, but one with selective command preprocessing performed.  I'm assuming that no such method exists, but I thought that it was worth asking about.  If such a mode does not exist, has anybody scoped out the work that would be required to use latex itself for this task?

Comment: while you can do simple cases with perl or latex to do the expansion, it's not in general possible even if you use latex to do the expansions as if you are writing out text you are (presumably) not typesetting and expansion depends on typeset values. By now though there are reasonably good heuristics for this in the standard tex to html convertors, latexml, tex4ht, mathjax would all understand the definitions you posted, so even though it's not possible in theory, in practice it may be that those solutions are good enough.