# Making \includeonlylecture{} only ignore frames but not global structure elements such as sections

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I am presently preparing lecture notes in `beamer`. I have the lecture course structured into parts, sections etc and I would like use the numbering scheme consistently throughout the course. Without doing a lot of manual copy-and-paste stuff this implies for me that a single `.tex` file (maybe with includes here and there) for the entire course is the best solution. But of course this means that LaTeX always has to process a lot of stuff and I always get a PDF with the entire course, which is not really practical.

To solve this, `beamer` class has the `\lecture` command and the accompanying `\includeonlylecture` command. However, if I use this, my structure will be broken, because Latex will ignore all structural elements (parts, sections, etc.) outside of the current lecture, producing new numberings for each lecture. Andrew's answer to [Entire course with beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52900/entire-course-with-beamer) provides an even more rigorous approach to the `\lecture` mechanism, but it will also ignore everything.

Therefore my question: How can I make `\includeonlylecture{}` to only ignore `\frame` commands and frame environments?

Here is a try of a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt, t, xcolor=dvipsnames, utf8x]{beamer}
\includeonlylecture{day2}

\begin{document}
\lecture{27. April 2014}{day1}
\part{one}
  \frame{Ignore this....}
  \section{one-one}
\lecture{24. April 2014}{day2}
  \section{one-two}
  \frame{Use this frame and let it be in section one-two}
\part{two}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution myself. Basically it redefines beamer's \beamer@section etc. macros such that most of the stuff performed at the start of a section (or part or subsection) is done, even, when it's not in the current lecture.

Here's the code for sections (the other two are very similar):

```
\long\def\beamer@section[#1]#2{%
  \beamer@savemode%
  \mode<all>%
    \refstepcounter{section}%
    \beamer@ifempty{#2}%
    {\long\def\secname{#1}\long\def\lastsection{#1}}%
    {\global\advance\beamer@tocsectionnumber by 1\relax%
      \long\def\secname{#2}%
      \long\def\lastsection{#1}%
      \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\beamer@sectionintoc{\the\c@section}{#2}{\the\c@page}{\the\c@part}%
        {\the\beamer@tocsectionnumber}}}%
    {\let\\=\relax\xdef\sectionlink{{Navigation\the\c@page}{\noexpand\secname}}}%
    \beamer@tempcount=\c@page\advance\beamer@tempcount by -1%
    \beamer@ifempty{#1}{}{%
      \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{\protect\sectionentry{\the\c@section}{#1}{\the\c@page}{\secname}{\the\c@part}}}%
      \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@sectionpages{\the\beamer@sectionstartpage}{\the\beamer@tempcount}}}%
      \addtocontents{nav}{\protect\headcommand{\protect\beamer@subsectionpages{\the\beamer@subsectionstartpage}{\the\beamer@tempcount}}}%
    }%
    \beamer@sectionstartpage=\c@page%
    \beamer@subsectionstartpage=\c@page%
    \def\insertsection{\expandafter\hyperlink\sectionlink}%
    \def\insertsubsection{}%
    \def\insertsubsubsection{}%
    \def\insertsectionhead{\hyperlink{Navigation\the\c@page}{#1}}%
    \def\insertsubsectionhead{}%
    \def\insertsubsubsectionhead{}%
    \def\lastsubsection{}%
    \Hy@writebookmark{\the\c@section}{\secname}{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section}{2}{toc}%
    \hyper@anchorstart{Outline\the\c@part.\the\c@section}\hyper@anchorend%
  \ifbeamer@inlecture
    \beamer@ifempty{#2}{\beamer@atbeginsections}{\beamer@atbeginsection}%
  \fi%
  \beamer@resumemode}%
```

The only thing that is omitted when we are not in the current lecture is the execution of the \AtBeginSection-type macros.

The solution works well in the way that all parts, sections and subsections prior to the current lecture are added to the table-of-contents. So I can maintain a consistent section numbering scheme throughout the lecture. However, it seems a bit weird to me that all the global structure elements after the current lecture are not added. This is not really painful butI remember that it was once their, but now it is gone.