# Conditionally include a package

Tags: packages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing parameters to a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document)

Is it possible to include a package conditionally depending on the value of a variable defined outside the document/preamble.

For example, I would like to accomplish the following: if I issue `make pdf-wide` somehow the target in the Makefile tells to `\usepackage{savetrees}`.

Comment: This has already been discussed [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document).

Comment: Voted to close this