# Include LaTeX version in document

Tags: latex-base

Is there any command or package to insert the version of LaTeX used to create a document? I am looking for a header or footer in the first page that says something like `compiled with pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.11-2.2 (TeX Live 2010)`.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to do this but print the version number of a particular package used. Presumably not, since not every package defines such a primitive...

Comment: @Seamus:  Check source2e.pdf for the implementation of `\ProvidesPackage` and you will see that there is a global name for the package with the version in it.  So as long as the package authors use that declaration you can find it in `\csname ver@<package>.sty\endcsname`.  Ask your own question, though; this is a separate issue.

Comment: I think that would be an excellent question. I will leave Seamus the honor of asking it. It would be great to have a (draft) section in your document with this information.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is `\pdftexbanner` primitive which will give you that message (works for both pdftex and luatex), but xetex don't seem to have a similar banner primitive.

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly why I was looking for.

Comment: Additionally, you can put this command inside a hyperref parameter to have this information in the document PDF metadata: \usepackage[pdftex, pdfauthor={}, pdfcreator={\pdftexbanner}]{hyperref}

Comment: for luatex version 0.95 use `\luatexbanner`.

Answer (score 6):

Not as specific as you want, but Pdftex has the primitive `\pdftexversion`, which is 100x the version number.

You can make a shell script that creates a file based on the first line of the output of `tex -v` (or whatever), that is `\input` by the Latex program.  Cf. the answers to the question [Passing parameters to a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document/) for pointers on how to do this.

Comment: `\pdftexversion` does not work: it gives me "You can't use \pdftexversion in vertical mode." and if I precede it with `\leavevmode` it gives me "You can't use \pdftexversion in horizontal mode."