# How to include ConteXt version in document?

Tags: context, context-mkiv

My question is exactly the same as this one:
[Include LaTeX version in document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4534/include-latex-version-in-document)

I want to include in my document: compiled with ConteXt version YYYY.MM.DD.

Is it possible to do it automatically or I am stuck to do it manually?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. @Marco, that sounds like an answer :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a list of the available commands to print version numbers (there are
more, though).

```
\starttext
  \starttabulate
    \NC \tex{contextformat}    \EQ \contextformat    \NC\NR
    \NC \tex{contextversion}   \EQ \contextversion   \NC\NR
    \NC \tex{contextkind}      \EQ \contextkind      \NC\NR
    \NC \tex{mksuffix}         \EQ \mksuffix         \NC\NR
    \NC \tex{contextmark}      \EQ \contextmark      \NC\NR
    \NC \tex{texenginename}    \EQ \texenginename    \NC\NR
    \NC \tex{texengineversion} \EQ \texengineversion \NC\NR
  \stoptabulate
\stoptext
```

[image: output]

The definitions can be found in [`context.mkiv`](https://gitorious.org/context/context/source/c98294bb885c3de180d966fa15772008efaa570c:tex/context/base/context.mkiv#L30-42) and [`syst-ini.mkiv`](https://gitorious.org/context/context/source/c98294bb885c3de180d966fa15772008efaa570c:tex/context/base/syst-ini.mkiv#L1067-1068).