# Available commands for including LaTeX version information in document

Tags: pdftex

[Already](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4534/include-latex-version-in-document) asked, it's possible to include the version of LaTeX in a PDF using `\pdftexbanner`. However, this is only one command. Is there a similar selection of commands as those presented for [ConteXt](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152450/104015) to allow more customization of the version information used in the document?

On my machine, `\pdftexbanner` produces:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/MacPorts 2015_9) kpathsea version 6.2.1
```

which is too verbose for my desired use.

Edit: it appears to be possible to programmatically [extract](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175749/104015) substrings of `\pdftexbanner`, but this doesn't seem to be the most straightforward or portable solution to building a custom version string.

Comment: Perhaps you should specify what you expect. Just the version string, the TeXLive etc string?

Comment: You can extract content from `\pdftexbanner` by techniques described in [How can I programmatically populate a PDF's pdfcreator field?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175717/5764)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer see the linked options available in ConteXt; I am after a similar selection of options.

Comment: @Werner is there not a pre-separated selection of commands for pdfTeX?

Comment: @user2943160 The TeX format itself has never had such 'version' commands whilst LaTeX is also quite old and again predates the stability of such banner strings for extracting the engine details. One can happily query `\fmtname` and `\fmtversion` for plain/LaTeX but I'm unclear from the question exactly what it is you want to know the data for (the engine, the system or the format).

Comment: @JosephWright probably mostly pdfLaTeX, but LaTeX also is probably useful (I'm trying to customize my PDF's metadata fields). I note that the `snapshot` package extracts version numbers and revision dates from somewhere for all of the packages used.