# Automatically include TexStudio version in LaTeX code

Tags: texstudio

When creating my .pdf with pdflatex in [TexStudio](https://www.texstudio.org/), I would like to automatically include the current TexStudio version in my LaTeX code, so that I can, for example, print it at the document.

In the same manner that we can include the LaTeX version through the command `\pdftexbanner` (See [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4534/include-latex-version-in-document))

Thanks, for any hint.

Comment: `\pdftexbanner` will not show you the version of latex, just of the underlying pdftex, the latex version is `\fmtversion` I have no idea about texstudio can't help with that sorry, why would you put the editor version in the document, it has no effect on the output??

Comment: First of all, thanks for clarification with `\fmtversion`; I take note. Second, in a sense, you are right, David, TexStudio has "no effect" on the output as a compiled document, but for me TexStudio is such an irreplaceable huge help on writing LaTeX code that I want to give the due credit in the documents I generate. I am sure you sympathize with it, because, as far as I know, you are doing the same with LaTeX: there is a lot of high quality free software out there, lots of altruistically invested hours that, at least (!), need to be acknowledged :). (Thanks for asking)