# Conditional compilation of beamer slides

Tags: beamer, compiling, conditionals

I'm preparing a beamer slideshow, and I will have to print slides.

I would rather use landscape mode slides, but it is possible that I need to use portrait mode ones. Sadly, I won't know until a few minutes before the talk, so I have to prepare two copies of the presentation.

I've tried to use conditional compilation, but it doesn't seem to work pretty well.
Basically, I would like to have something like this:

```
    \newif\ifwide
    \widetrue
```

And then I would write something like this:

```
    \begin{frame}{A frame}
        Some text (...)
\ifwide
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}{A second frame}
\fi
        Some text (continued)
    \end{frame}
```

This particular example doesn't work (pdflatex reports `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{frame} (followed by: )`). What should I do to have the frame contents split on two frames in landsape mode, but not in portrait mode?

Comment: The `frame` environment of `beamer` is a pseudo-environment, i.e. actually a macro which reads everything until `\end{frame}` as argument. This is the reason why if-switches don't work here.

Comment: I see, thanks. Is there a way to have the `\if`s processed before the pseudo-environment expands?

Comment: Related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document (and see my answer).  This is a place I like to use docstrip.  Wish I could write up an answer for you right now, but I don't have the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following solution wraps each potential frame in its own environment and both of these in a parent environment. In wide mode the inner ones are not doing anything except setting the frame title and the outer environment is the frame. In the other mode the outer is a no-op and the inner are the frames.
This uses the `environment` key of the `frame` environment to tell it which `\end` ends the frame content.

This might not (yet) support the full range of `frame` optional arguments (`<>`, `[< >]` etc.).

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newif\ifwide
\widetrue

\ifwide

\newenvironment<>{frames}[1][]{%
  \begin{frame}#2[environment=frames,#1]%
}{%
  \end{frame}%
}
\newenvironment<>{firstframe}[2][]{
  \frametitle{#2}%
}{}%
\newenvironment<>{secondframe}[2][]{}{}%

\else

\newenvironment<>{frames}[1][]{%
}{%
}
\newenvironment<>{firstframe}[1][]{
  \begin{frame}#2[environment=firstframe,#1]%
}{%
  \end{frame}%
}%
\newenvironment<>{secondframe}[1][]{
  \begin{frame}#2[environment=firstframe,#1]%
}{%
  \end{frame}%
}%

\fi

\begin{document}

\begin{frames}
\begin{firstframe}{A frame}
    Some text (...)
\end{firstframe}
\begin{secondframe}{A second frame}
    Some text (continued)
\end{secondframe}
\end{frames}

\end{document}
```