# Using tilde `~` in csname in Beamer

Tags: macros, beamer, tilde, catcodes

In `beamer`, I would like to be able to use the tilde character `~` in the name of a command sequence. I tried with adjusting catcodes. While this was successful with the standard `article` class, it failed with `beamer`:

Working `article` example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\section{cs with tilde}

\catcode`\~=12%

\expandafter\def\csname cswith~\endcsname{foo}
cs value:\csname cswith~\endcsname.

\catcode`\~=13%

\end{document}
```

Beamer example producing `Missing \endcsname inserted` error:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{cs with tilde}

\catcode`\~=12%

\expandafter\def\csname cswith~\endcsname{foo}
cs value:\csname cswith~\endcsname.

\catcode`\~=13%

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work outside the frame? Also it's safer to do ``\begingroup\catcode`\~=12 \expandafter … \endgroup``, since this will restore the whatever catcode `~` had.

Comment: Outside it seems to work, at least no error. But I want it to work inside the frame environment too.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the reason is the same as in this question: [Conditional compilation of beamer slides](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12563/1235). As Martin Scharrer notes there, the `frame` environment is a pseudo-environment, i.e. actually a macro that reads everything until `\end{frame}` as an argument.

Comment: You must - as with verbatim content - use the fragile option. `\begin{frame}[fragile]`

Comment: @Ulrike: this produces `Runaway argument? ! File ended while scanning use of \next. <inserted text> \par` error, with whatever frame content. `fragile` is not an option anyway, because I need the problem solved for package writing purposes. (Don't want the user to set the `fragile` option.)

Comment: @Alexander: Using `[fragile]` works for your minimal example.

Comment: `[fragile]` works fine for me and `beamer 2010/06/21 development version 3.10` (and it should work fine!).

Comment: @Ulrike: While it seem not to be what the OP wants, it is a good general solution for catcode changes in `beamer` `frame`s, so you really should post it as an answer.

Comment: @Martin: `fragile` is mentioned in your answer and this is quite enough at my opinion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Hendik Vogt already mentioned (by citing me) in the question comments this doesn't work because `beamer` actually reads the content as macro argument and therefore the catcode change comes to late.

One way to solve this is already mentioned by Ulrike Fischer: use the `[fragile]` option to make `beamer` process the `frame` content in a way which allows catcode changes.

You could also define all the code you require outside the frame as a macro while the catcode changes are in effect and then simply use that macro inside the frame. The catcode is important when the `~` is *read* not when it is executed/processed.

However, I would solve it quite simple: Use `\string~` instead to get `~` as a string:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{cs with tilde}

\expandafter\def\csname cswith\string~\endcsname{foo}%
cs value:\csname cswith\string~\endcsname.

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Note that you can also use `\csdef{cswith\string~}{foo}` and `\csuse{cswidth\string~}` if you load the `etoolbox` package.

---

Or even simpler: Redefine `~` locally to produce `\string~`. Then you have to type less if you need it more often. However, any normal `~` inside the frame or used by macros will not work as usual anymore.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{cs with tilde}

\def~{\string~}%
\expandafter\def\csname cswith~\endcsname{foo}%
cs value:\csname cswith~\endcsname.

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will use the `\def~{\string~}` answer approach embedded into a `\begingroup \endgroup` bracket to limit its effect to the scope of the user command I am writing.

Comment: @Alexander: Why not use `\def~{\ifincsname\string~\else\nobreak\ \fi}`? I didn't test, but I think that should do the right thing.