# Beamer conditional pdf file generation

Tags: beamer, conditionals, compiling

I would like to know if there is a method to generate beamer pdf presentation based on conditions. For example:

-Main Beamer presentation:

```
Slide 1
Slide 2
Slide 3
Slide 4
Slide 5
```

-For the first presentation (pdf file):

```
Slide 1 (hidden)
Slide 2 (hidden)
Slide 3
Slide 4
Slide 5
```

-For the second presentation (pdf file):

```
Slide 1
Slide 2 (hidden)
Slide 3
Slide 4 (hidden)
Slide 5 (hidden)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I've never tried with `beamer`, but the `comment` package might help you here. `:)`

Comment: @Paulo, I think that **comment** will not work here. Please, see the first comment [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12563/conditional-compilation-of-beamer-slides?rq=1)

Comment: @Papiro: Since you're hiding *entire* slides, this 'should' work (either using `\if`s, or `comment`) - haven't tested. The comments in the linked post references the fact of inserting conditionals *across* environment boundaries.

Comment: @Papiro: I made a quick MWE and the `comment` package worked with `beamer`, but my solution is ugly. I'll wait if someone comes up with a better idea than mine. `:)`

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Conditional typesetting / build](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build/)

Comment: You might also have a look at the [tagging](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tagging) package by **[Brent.Longborough](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/344/brent-longborough)**, which was created in [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10996/document-configuration-via-tags-or-labels).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a specifically beamerish (not to be confused with *Beamish*) way to do this.  It works by taking advantage of the fact that beamer's *modes* are not defined from a specified list.  Indeed, searching the code then the `trans` mode is conspicuous by its absence.  In reality, `trans` is simply "not `beamer`".  Similarly `handout`.  So you can define a new mode and the overlay specifications will work matching that mode.  The only snag is that the in-frame slide count has a specific match for `beamer`.  This means that a generic specification, say `\only<3>{some text}` will be viewed as `\only<beamer:3>{some text}`.  So to make the new modes act as `beamer` and not as `trans` or `article`, it's necessary to subvert this test.  This means that one needs the Dreaded MakeAtLetter of Bexhill-on-Sea.  Moreover, I haven't thoroughly tested this so there may be more situations I haven't considered.

Anyway, here's the code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66508/86}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\beamersetmode}[1]{%
  \gdef\beamer@currentmode{#1}%
    \gdef\beamer@@@decodefind##1:##2|{%
      \beamer@ifempty{##2}%
      {\beamer@decodefind #1:##1:}%
      {\beamer@decodefind ##1:##2}}}
\makeatother

\beamersetmode{A}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<A:0>
Slide One \only<2>{with overlays}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}<A:0|B:0>
Slide Two \only<2>{with overlays}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
Slide Three \only<2>{with overlays}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}<B:0>
Slide Four \only<2>{with overlays}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}<B:0>
Slide Five \only<2>{with overlays}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}<presentation:0>
Slide Six will never be shown
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And this produces the following.  Change the `\beamersetmode` to `\beamersetmode{B}` or omit it altogether to get the other versions.

[image: conditional frame inclusion]

Note: don't use `first` and `second` because `second` is already used for something to do with having slides on a second screen.

Answer (score 5):

I think that in `beamer` terminology you mean to omit certain frames (rather than slides). The comments suggest some generic ways to omit sections but beamer has a bult in way to drop certain frames.

```
\begin{frame}<0>

\end{frame}
```

will not appear in the output.

This is a special case of a more general conditional processing feature see section 8.4 of the  beamer manual.