# How do I execute some commands conditionally?

Tags: conditionals

What would be the correct way to execute commands conditionally in LaTeX?

Here is the problem I am having. I have a `book_pdf.tex` where I wish to define the style of the book as it would look in a PDF. Then I have `book_epub.tex` where I wish to define the style of the book as it would look in an EPUB format.

Then I also have `chapter1.tex`, `chapter2.tex`, etc. In each of these chapters I have to do micro adjustments for each format. So I am thinking that I need to define a variable in either `ebook_pdf.tex` (something like `var pdf = true` in pseudosyntax), and then in `chapter1.tex`, I want to check if it's the pdf template that is used (something like `if pdf then insert \newline`). Or if it's the epub format, then I want to define `epub` variable and do stuff like `if epub then \begin{lstlistings}[basicstyle=\smaller] else insert \begin{lstlistings}[basicstyle=\small]`.

Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document/

Comment: @xport: Are *you* seriously chastising Peteris for bad behavior?

Comment: @Caramdir: I support Peteris!

Comment: @xport: Then you should know that Peteris wouldn't be affected by that rule (as he has posted less than 50 questions in total so far). And they seem pretty substantial (though this one has been asked in several variations before).

Comment: @Caramdir: I just want to let him know there is a good article that he might have not read yet.

Answer (score 5):

Define your own document class with an optional argument, eg for `myClass.cls`:

```
\newif\ifEPUB\EPUBfalse
\DeclareOption{EPUB}{\EPUBtrue}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{book}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{book}
\RequirePackage{...}
...
```

in your document you can use:

```
\documentclass[EPUB,11pt,a4paper,...]{myClass}
\usepackage{...}
...
\begin{document}
...
\ifEPUB
  ...
\else
  ...
\fi
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 Why did you not use `*` for the first `\DeclareOption`?

Comment: @xport: http://ctan.org/pkg/clsguide

Comment: there is a different syntax for the starred version!