# conditional highlighting with soul

Tags: conditionals, soul, changes, journal-publishing

The journal [PLoS ONE](http://www.plosone.org), says in the [FAQ](http://blogs.plos.org/everyone/authors/qa/#rsub)

```
When submitting your revision, you will need to include the following new files:
[...] A ‘clean’ copy of your revised manuscript.
A revised manuscript with tracked changes. [...]
```

I'm using [`soul`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/soul)'s `\hl` to highlight changes. So, I also need a version that doesn't highlight changes. To accomplish this, I added the following code. The `\renewcommand{\hl}[1]{#1}` is intended as a no-op. So the "clean" version
would use `\highlightfalse` and the version with tracked changes would use `\highlighttrue`.

This appears to work, but I'm wondering if there are any problems with this approach, or better ways to do it.

```
\newif\ifhighlight
% COMMENT OUT \highlighttrue or \highlightfalse
\highlighttrue % or
%\highlightfalse
\ifhighlight
\else
\renewcommand{\hl}[1]{#1}
\fi
```

Comment: Have you seen this: [TrackChanges - Collaborative editing of LaTeX documents](http://trackchanges.sourceforge.net/index.html)?

Comment: @Werner: I haven't, no. So this is a substitute for `soul`?

Comment: Searching on `trackchanges` on this site also brings up [changes](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/changes/). Can anyone comment on either of these? `changes` doesn't use `soul`, which might be a plus, since it is unmaintained and buggy. And the most recent update of `changes` is in 2011.

Comment: If you do want to use highlighting with `soul`, then this approach seems fine to me (except that you example is missing the `\newif\ifhighlight`). Depending on how you compile your file, [Passing parameters to a document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document) (or any of its near-duplicates) could be of interest.

Comment: @Faheem: No, TrackChanges is not an alternative to `soul` since `soul` is not focussed on the realm of tracking document changes; it deals with a bunch of other formatting. TrackChanges provides a very specific/tailored tracking functionality. Using the suggested `\newif\ifhighlight` should work fine.

Comment: @Caramdir: Oops, forgot to include `\newif\ifhighlight`. Fixed now.

Comment: I'm surprised no-one mentioned `latexdiff` yet.

Comment: @Caramdir: Could you write a short answer?

Comment: @lockstep: I was reminded by this question by your comment. For the record, I wound up switching to the the changes package (prompted by the comment by Werner). That was quite satisfactory. Is it worth adding an answer detailing that? Is your concern getting the question answered? If so, I guess I can answer and accept, if that would be Ok with everyone. For the record, I would not recommend `soul`. It has too many problems, and is unmaintained.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you do want to use highlighting with `soul`, then this approach seems fine to me. Even better would be to create a sematic macro, like

```
\ifhighlight
    \let\change\hl
\else
    \newcommand{\change}[1]{#1}
\fi
```

Depending on how you compile your file, [Passing parameters to a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document) (or any of its near-duplicates) could be of interest.

Since the trickery `soul` has to do can cause trouble, it might be worth to have a look packages that are explicitly designed for your application, like the [`changes`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/changes) package.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments above, I wound up using the `changes` package, and would not recommend the `soul` package, as it is unmaintained and I've had problems with it.