# Turning soul:hl function into an environment

Tags: environments, soul

I am using the function `hl` from package `soul` to highlight text. I would like to create a specific environment, that would be used for the highlighting. I tried with `newenvironment`, but did not figure how to get it right (see also this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64744/environment-to-underline-strikeout-for-comparing-versions)). I tried also using the package `environ` to define a new environment, but am now facing an error message from soul: *Package soul Error: Reconstruction failed. I came across hyphenatable material enclosed in group braces,
which I can't handle. Either drop the braces or make the material
unbreakable using an \mbox (\hbox).*

Any idea how I can embed `hl` into an evnironment?

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}


\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\NewEnviron{newtext}{\hl{\BODY}}
%\NewEnviron{newtext}{\BODY}

\begin{document}


\hl{I work well when called  as a function }

\begin{newtext} I don't seem to work when called as an enviornment. \end{newtext}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to expand `\BODY` before `\hl` absorbs it.  The way to do this is with `\expandafter`, which skips over one token and (once-)expands the next, before executing the skipped-over token.  Since `\BODY` is two tokens ahead of `\hl`, with an intervening left brace `{`, one must also include an `\expandafter` before the `{`, as well, so that the first `\expandafter` will expand the 2nd `\expandafter` which, in turn, will skip over the `{` and expand `\BODY`.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}


\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\NewEnviron{newtext}{\expandafter\hl\expandafter{\BODY}}
%\NewEnviron{newtext}{\BODY}

\begin{document}


\hl{I work well when called  as a function }

\begin{newtext} I don't seem to work when called as an enviornment. \end{newtext}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: beautiful! Do you mind giving a succinct explanation/link about expanding for further ref?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Matifou I have edited my answer to do so.

Comment: thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 6):

An expl3 version:

[image: hl expl3]

with environment option to change the colour.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse} %part of kernel now
\usepackage{xcolor,soul}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment { newtext } { o +b } {
    \IfNoValueF {#1}
     {      
        \sethlcolor{#1}
        }
    \hl { #2 } 
}{}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}


\hl{I work well when called  as a function }

\begin{newtext} 
I don't seem to work when called as an environment.

I don't seem to work when called as an environment.

I don't seem to work when called as an environment.

\end{newtext}

---

\begin{newtext}[green]
I don't seem to work when called as an environment.

I don't seem to work when called as an environment.

I don't seem to work when called as an environment.

\end{newtext}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are willing to use LuaLaTeX you can use my `lua-ul` package to avoid having to use `environ` and friends alltogether and define a "regular" environment instead. Then there are also less restrictions about possible arguments:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,luacolor,lua-ul}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{newtext}[1][yellow] {%
   \luaul@setcolor{#1}%
   \@highLight
}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\highLight{I work well when called  as a function }

\begin{newtext} 
I work well when called as an environment.

I work well when called as an environment.

I work well when called as an environment.

\end{newtext}

---

\begin{newtext}[green]
I work well when called as an environment.

I work well when called as an environment.

I work well when called as an environment.

Even allows using e.g.\@ \verb|\verb| when used as an environment.
\end{newtext}


\end{document}
```

[image: The output of the code above demonstrating that the highlighting works]