# Passing more command line argument

Tags: optional-arguments

I am new to latex. I would like to pass command line arguments (probably more) to `\newcommand` macro and expecting output like below.

```
if input is 1
      /include {1.tex}  

else if input is 2
      /include {2.tex}
else if input is 3
      /include {3.tex}     
else if input is 1 and 2          
      /include {1.tex}        
      /include {2.tex}
else if input is 1 and 2  and 3       
      /include {1.tex} 
      /include {2.tex}    
      /include {3.tex}
```

and so on. I have heard some `xkeyval, xargs` packages do like this. But i am not sure about its implementations.

How can i give too many arguments to latex?
How can i parse/differentiate the arguments and then pass accordingly?

Comment: It looks like you want to have something like a `\multiinput{1,2,3}`, in other words input is the name of the files to be added. Am I right?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply.Input is not the name of file. It is actually any word (for example bird, vehicle), depends on the word i should add files probably, in following loop (ex:if word =bird then /include{parrot.tex} /include{dove.tex} else if word = vehicle then /include{car.tex} /include{bike.tex} )

Comment: Related question: [automation - Passing parameters to a document - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a `umaraman.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\ifdefined\umafiles\else\let\umafiles\@empty\fi
\newcommand{\umainput}[1]{%
 \ifx\umafiles\@empty\input{#1}\else
   \@for\next:=\umafiles\do{%
     \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{#1}{\next}=\z@\input{#1}\fi
   }
 \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\umainput{uma1}
\umainput{uma2}
\umainput{uma3}
\umainput{uma4}
\umainput{uma5}
\end{document}
```

Of course the files can be named as you wish. If you call from the command line

```
pdflatex "\def\umafiles{uma1,uma3}\input{umaraman.tex}"
```

only `uma1` and `uma3` will be input. If you instead call normally

```
pdflatex umaraman.tex
```

all files will be input.