# Replace from a list of possible strings

Tags: macros

I'm creating a large number of identical documents in LaTeX, with only the address changing (and the address will be only 1 of 5 possible )

So if my list of possible addresses is:
`DC | 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington, DC
FV | 2014 Forest Hills Drive, Fayetteville, NC
NY | 1 World Trade Center, New York, NY
SP | 742 Evergreen Terrace, Springfield, USA`

I want to be able to type (for example) `\fillinadd{DC}` and have it fill in the proper address in text, so if I were to have a letter like:

```
\documentclass{letter}

\signature{Maurice Moss}
\newcommand{\fillinadd}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{
Fire Department \\
\fillinadd{DC}}

\opening{Dear Sir / Madam,}
Fire! Fire! Help me! 123 Carrendon Road. Looking forward to hearing from you.
\closing{All the best,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

It would replace the "DC" with "1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington, DC", but if I put in "SP" it would print 742 Evergreen Terrace instead.

Alternately, if there is a better way to identify these possible addresses (ie #1, #2, etc), I'm fine with using that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need five addresses, then define them as commands. You could put the definitions in a separate file and input it to the main file, or just put them in the preamble.

```
\newcommand{\DC}{%
    123 Main Street,\\ 
    Washington, DC%
}
\newcommand{\LA}{%
    123 Main Street,\\ 
    Los Angeles, CA%
}
```

How you write the commands will be determined by their eventual use. Here I'm assuming something like this:

```
\newcommand{\fromaddress}{%
    \noindent%
    \begin{tabular}{l}
    #1\\
    \end{tabular}%
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
\fromaddress{\DC}
```

Comment: This makes sense. My eventual use is to be able to manipulate them using  the command line (a la [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104391/passing-more-command-line-argument)), so I can generate these files on the fly. I'm assuming I would define `\fromaddress{}` to be either whatever I have inputted, or `\DC{}` if it's undefined.

Comment: I got it working! All you have to do is make your address commands (see @touhami 's answer), and then have a command named `\fromaddress` where you put the address, and then have a line like so: `\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\fromaddress}}{\newcommand{\fromaddress}{\DC}}{}` that you can use. Finally, when running pdflatex, use something like this: `pdflatex "\def\fromaddress{\NY} \input{resume.tex}"` to change the address.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I do

```
\documentclass{letter}

\signature{Maurice Moss}

\newcommand{\DC}{1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington, DC}
\newcommand{\FV}{2014 Forest Hills Drive, Fayetteville, NC}
\newcommand{\NY}{1 World Trade Center, New York, NY}
\newcommand{\SP}{742 Evergreen Terrace, Springfield, USA}


\begin{document}

\begin{letter}{
Fire Department \\ \DC}

\opening{Dear Sir / Madam,}
Fire! Fire! Help me! 123 Carrendon Road. Looking forward to hearing from you.
\closing{All the best,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```