# Compiling latex files from terminal with and without a command

Tags: minitoc

I have used \faketableofcontents in my file.  I need to compile the file twice -- once with \faketableofcontents present and once with \faketableofcontents commented out. I wonder if there is a way to compile the file from terminal and use a true or false argument which specify whether \faketableofcontents must be included or ignored during compilation.

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1492/15925 help?

Comment: @AndrewSwann Yes the page is precisely what I am looking for.

Comment: Good.  Then we should close your question as a duplicate.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Yes please.