# what Makefile to produce slides and handouts a common file

Tags: beamer

a handy feature of `beamer` is to be able to produce slides or a handout. you "just" have to change a line in the source. a known solution is to use 2 different files forthe different options with a common input to the slides, but find this solution non economic.

however, I wished to produce the slides and the handout more naturally using a Makefile.

Is it possible to pass at the command line (for instance to `lualatex`) an option that can be used by beamer and include that in a Makefile?

Comment: FWIW, in ConTeXt conditional processing is handled using [`modes`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Modes), and `context` has a command line option to enable or disable [modes](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Modes).

Comment: I found a related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document

Answer (score 6):

You can execute it like that:

```
pdflatex  '\PassOptionsToClass{handout}{beamer} \input{presentation}'
```

This will still create `presentation.pdf` and overwrite the normal version of the PDF.

Or alternatively you can use three files and create the following documents:

```
% notes.tex
\PassOptionsToClass{notes=only}{beamer}
\input{presentation}

% handout.tex
\PassOptionsToClass{handout}{beamer}
\input{presentation}
```

which will create `notes.pdf` and `handout.pdf` instead without any need for a compiler options.

The main file can now easily be compiled simply using `pdflatex presentation` and the notes and handout with `pdflatex notes` and `pdflatex handout`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this is to use `sed`. I'm not great with Regualr Expressions but here's the basic command to do it.

`sed "s/documentclass[[?][a-zA-Z0-9,]*[]?]/documentclass[handout]/g" main.tex > handout.tex`

This will create a second file. I know there is a way to store the options it finds and keep them in. It's not that complicated but I haven't taken the time to do it (another problem for another day).

Anyway, I then string the `sed` command with the `lualatex` commands for both the presentation and the handouts like so:

`sed "s/documentclass[[?][a-zA-Z0-9,]*[]?]/documentclass[handout]/g" main.tex > handout.tex && lualatex --jobname=Presentation --synctex=1 --output-directory=Presentation main.tex && lualatex --jobname=Handout --synctex=1 --output-directory=Handout handout.tex`

This could obviously be done as three separate commands.

Comment: May be worth writing a script for this. Would simplify things.