# Draft compilation without changing code

Tags: compiling, draft

I usually have my `documentclass` not in the body file but in a different one, so when I want to switch between draft and final modes I have to change the file I'm working on and look for that line.

My question is: is there any way of configuring TexMaker (in my case) in order to have one compiling **command** to build the draft version and another one to produce the final one?

Comment: Possible duplicate; see, for instance, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1495/47522