# Generate multiple PDFs for different document versions in a single build

Tags: pdftex, conditionals, etoolbox

I am writing a document for a software which has two versions. Most of the content in the document is the same except few specific details. Right now, I am using the conditionals to build the document for a specific file, like so,

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
..
\newtoggle{version5}    
\togglefalse{version5}

\iftoggle{version5} {
    \title{Version 5 document}
} {
    \title{Version 6 document}
}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter 1}
        \iftoggle{version5} {
            \section{Version 5 section}
        } {
            \section{Version 6 section}
        }
\end{document}
```

This works prefectly, but the problem is everytime I need either of the document, I need to `toggle` the variables each time. Is there a way to build both the document in a single run?

Comment: This might help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This uses the `shell-escape` features (`\immediate\write18`) and writes `\togglefalse{version5}` or `\toggletrue{version5}` to a file called `foo.cfg`

This `foo.cfg` is read by `foo.tex`.

The compilation is done in a subshell, the rename can be done with the `--jobname=` option of the `pdflatex` binary (or `xelatex` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}


\newwrite\foocfg% Get a file handle

\newcommand{\prepareconfigfile}[2]{%
\immediate\openout\foocfg=#1 % open the file in #1 -- Be carefull here!
\immediate\write\foocfg{%
  \expandafter\string\csname toggle#2\endcsname{version5}%
  }%
\immediate\closeout\foocfg% Close the file
}



\begin{document}
\prepareconfigfile{foo.cfg}{true}
\immediate\write18{pdflatex --jobname=footrue.pdf foo}

\prepareconfigfile{foo.cfg}{false}
\immediate\write18{pdflatex --jobname=foofalse.pdf foo}
\end{document}
```

Compilation source (`foo.tex`)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newtoggle{version5}    
\togglefalse{version5}

\InputIfFileExists{foo.cfg}{}{}

\iftoggle{version5}{%
  \title{Version 5 document}
}{%
  \title{Version 6 document}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
    \chapter{Chapter 1}
    \iftoggle{version5}{%
      \section{Version 5 section}
    }{%
      \section{Version 6 section}
    }%
\end{document}
```

Comment: I found that we can rename the output of pdfLatex without using the `mv` command (Gnu-Utils). We could generate a name that we want by using the `job-name` parameter with the `pdflatex` command, like so, `pdflatex -job-name=my_file_name foo`.

Comment: @Rakesh: Oh yes, I had that in mind too, but on LInux it's `--jobname=...` and I failed, but I did use the wrong order! Thanks, I will update!

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in my comment, the question [Passing parameters to a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document) allready points in a right direction.

File Master.tex

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newtoggle{version5}
\IfStrEq{\jobname}{\detokenize{Version5}}{\toggletrue{version5}}{\togglefalse{version5}}

\iftoggle{version5} {
    \title{Version 5 document}
} {
    \title{Version 6 document}
}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Chapter 1}
        \iftoggle{version5} {
            \section{Version 5 section}
        } {
            \section{Version 6 section}
        }
\jobname
\end{document}
```

After that you can add a (or two) symlink(s). One named Version5.tex and the other named Version6.tex. This works even under Windows (but needs the cmd-line or a Batch-File and administrator rights; I can provide a batch-file if needed).

After that, you can compile Version5.tex and Version6.tex and get the following output:
[image: Version5]
[image: Version6]

Answer (score 5):

Here is another solution based on the file name. Create a file `Master.tex` and two symbolic links to it: `Version5.tex` and `Version6.tex`. When compiling one of these, a switch `versionV` is set to true if `Version5` is being compiled and set to false otherwise.

I have used the more low level `\newif` to create a switch and `\ifversionV` to branch based on its value. No extra packages are necessary.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifversionV
\makeatletter
\edef\@tempa{\jobname}
\def\@tempb{Version5}
\@onelevel@sanitize\@tempb
\ifx\@tempa\@tempb \versionVtrue\else\versionVfalse\fi
\makeatother

\ifversionV
    \title{Version 5}
\else
    \title{Version 6}
\fi

\author{Franz K.}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

One morning, as Gregor Samsa was waking up from anxious dreams, he
discovered that in his bed he had been changed into a monstrous verminous
bug. He lay on his armour-hard back and saw, as he lifted his head up a
little, his brown, arched abdomen divided up into rigid bow-like sections.

\end{document}
```