# Typesetting with different values of a boolean

Tags: compiling, versions

In my document I have defined a few booleans (like `etu` in order to hide some parts of the document for the students, or `mono` which activates the monochrome option of xcolor).

My aim is now to provide different versions of the pdf, **with just one typesetting**, depending on the booleans `etu` and `mono`. Unfortunately I don't know how I can do this.

Comment: Also this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/461973/134574

Comment: I completed my question : I would like to create different versions, with just one typeset. I think that https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461973/generating-multiple-versions-of-a-document-using-options does not treat this problem.

Comment: Your addition (... with just one typesetting ...) is not possible. I assume you're referring to "clicking the compile button just once" here. Depending on the GUI you're using, you can specify numerous output processes that accompanies a single click. For example, under TeXnicCentre, one can specify [separate pre- and post-processor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJ6Oj.png) sequences which could possibly compile using a pre-specified format with certain options and rename the output, then do it all over again with a different format/options...

Comment: You want to create more than one PDF in a single run of LaTeX? I'm afraid that's not possible.

Comment: Maybe with some tricks, look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5228/can-one-tex-file-output-to-multiple-pdf-files or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258687/generate-multiple-pdfs-for-different-document-versions-in-a-single-build or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/162042/multiple-pdf-generation-with-one-tex-file etc.