# Is it possible to place compiler tags in the latex document such that one .tex document can produce two different documents sharing similar content?

Tags: compiling, bash

I'm writing a document and I need two versions.

Version one gives the outline and details of the project. It gives a method overview, data, results and conclusion etc. The methods are very mathematical/computational but this is to be a very non-technical report for managements et al. etc.

The second version is the first version plus additional extra sections detailing the technical stuff, algorithms, mathematical derivations, arguments used in command lines and details of house software etc. It's stuff that is just too in depth for a non-technical report, but there should I personally or a team member ever need to refer to it in the future and remind ourselves of the exact details.

I don't really want to write two documents as it will be updated frequently and will be hard to keep tract of two large documents and ensure they share the same material. I noted that the compiler can be told to leave out and sections between \iffalse and \fi commands. Is there a similar command such that anything between two commands is left out (or in) given a command line argument (I'm on Linux). I'm familiar with bash scripts, but can't see how to do this?

Comment: If technical/non-technical chunks of texts are not too mixed, the best is write and maintain one or both type of text chunks in separate `.tex` subdocuments and show/hide them  in the main document using `\input{subdocument}`  and `%\input{subdocument}` . Otherwise,  switch between `\def\technical{#1}` and  `\def\technical{}` to show/hide the `\technical{parts}`.

Comment: boris veytsman gave a presentation on a very similar topic at tug 2015.  a video of his presentation is posted at http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/tex-and-controlled-access-to-information/.  the proceedings aren't out yet (and when they are, viewing will be limited to tug members for a year after publication), but should be available soon at http://tug.org/TUGboat/Contents/contents36-2.html.

Answer (score 2):

My quick-and-dirty way would be using the `environ` package. Something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifFullVersion
\FullVersiontrue% or \FullVersionfalse

\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{fullversion}{\ifFullVersion\expandafter\BODY\fi}

\begin{document}

This is always here.

\begin{fullversion}
This is here only if the full version is switched on.
\end{fullversion}

This is always here either.
\end{document}
```

This of course implies that you declare `\FullVersiontrue` or `\FullVersionfalse` manually in the preamble. But it's not difficult to write a small shell script which adds the desired line, say, after `\begin{document}`.

Surely the `comment` package can be used in similar way. Or even the basic `\includeonly` command could be used for this, but this might be more cumbersome in connection with a shell-script approach.

Answer (score 0):

Ok OP here, So I have found one solution that is working. Its a modification of Neil Olver's solution here: [Passing parameters to a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document) . The bash script I've used is below:

```
#!/bin/bash "Make_Doc.sh"
if [ "$2" = "-F" ]
then
    echo "Full Doc Printed"
    LatexInput="\def\flagOne{1}"
else
    echo "Short Doc Printed"
    LatexInput="\def\flagTwo{1}"
fi
pdflatex "$LatexInput \input{$1.tex}"
```

Then in the latex document place all text that is only to appear when when argument 2 in the command line is -F (i.e Make_Doc.sh foo.tex -F
) between these statements:

```
\ifdefined\flagOne
Text here
\fi
```

A full example is:

```
\begin{document}
.
.
.
Text to appear in both documents
.
.
.
\ifdefined\flagOne
Text to appear in only in full document
\fi
.
.
.
Text to appear in both documents
.
.
.
\ifdefined\flagOne
Text to appear in only in full document
\fi
.
.
.
Text to appear in both documents
.
.
.
\end{document}
```

This could most likely be extended to produce any number of different document versions by simply defining more flags. A better solution may exist however.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a new conditional `\ifsimple` and structure your text using `\if .. \else .. \fi`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newif\ifsimple
\simpletrue 
\simplefalse

\author{Franz K.}

\ifsimple
    \title{The Problem With Bugs}
\else
    \title{Metamorphosis}
\fi

\begin{document}
\maketitle

One morning, as Gregor Samsa was waking up from anxious dreams, he
discovered that in his bed he had been changed into a monstrous verminous
bug. He lay on his armour-hard back and saw, as he lifted his head up a
little, his brown, arched abdomen divided up into rigid bow-like sections.

\ifsimple\else
\emph{Provide a scientific discussion here that is only intended for
experts on metamorphosis.}
\fi

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]