# Generate oneside and twoside version at the same time

Tags: compiling, document-classes

Is there a possibility that with compiling my latex document all the time two PDFs are created (a oneside and twoside version). So in my case only the first line would be different for the two versions:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{scrreprt}
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside]{scrreprt}
```

Comment: Probably with `arara` or `latexmk` combined with one of [these answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document) you can automatically compile your document twice, one for `oneside` and another for `twoside`.

Comment: Printing on a Möbius strip?

Comment: don't use `\documentclass` in your `.tex` file and compile with `pdflatex --jobname one \documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{scrreprt}\input{myfilename} & pdflatex --jobname two \documentclass[11pt, a4paper, twoside]{scrreprt}\input{myfilename}`

Comment: @Bernard For printing on a Möbius strip you only need `\documentclass[11pt, a4paper, oneside]{scrreprt}` ;)

Answer (score 1):

If it's easier for you, you can also alter your `.tex` source file within a batch script during compilation.  For example, here is an example using a `DOS` script.

Given a `sample.tex` file:

```
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
Hello
\end{document}
```

The following batch file will create two different `tex` files and process them to give the shown output.

```
echo \documentclass[10pt]{article} > temp10.tex
type sample.tex >> temp10.tex
pdflatex temp10.tex

echo \documentclass[12pt]{article} > temp12.tex
type sample.tex >> temp12.tex
pdflatex temp12.tex
```

[image]

[image]