# \typein and user-friendliness: how can I prevent errors from occurring if the user presses arrow keys or delete?

Tags: compiling, fun, typein

I'm writing a document for my friend Sir Galahad to compile, and I'm using `\typein` to customize it: I'll give him the file `bridge.tex`, he will run `pdflatex bridge.tex`, and during compilation the terminal asks him a few questions, and modifies the document based on his answers.

I won't be around when Galahad is compiling this document, so I'd like to make this more "user-friendly," in that it shouldn't be difficult to use and should be forgiving of mistakes.

Concretely, the issue is: **if the user wants to edit their input, the delete key and arrow keys cause errors. Is there a way to prevent this?** Backspace works fine, though.

---

Here's an example of what's going on.

```
% bridge.tex
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\typein[\yourname]{What... is your name?}
\typein[\yourquest]{What... is your quest?}
\typein[\yourcolor]{And what... is your favorite colour?}

\begin{frame}{Sir \yourname{} of Camelot}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Name: \yourname
    \item Quest: \yourquest
    \item Favorite colour: \yourcolor
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Sir Galahad compiles this and everything goes fine until the third question: he first put down "blue," but when he tries to use the left-arrow key to edit this to "yellow," it doesn't work as expected:

```
What... is your name?

\yourname=Sir Galahad
What... is your quest?

\yourquest=To seek the Grail
And what... is your favorite colour?

\yourcolor=Blue!^[[D^[[D^[[D^[[D
```

Each time the left-arrow key is pressed, `^[[D` is inserted, and this is passed to LaTeX, where it causes the error `Text line contains invalid character.` A similar problem happens with the delete key.

Is there a flag that allows Sir Galahad to use these keys? If not, can I write a workaround for `\typein` that would work? I'm willing to use `\write18` if necessary.

Comment: Throw the Holy hand grenade and count to three  (but only to three, not to four!) ;-) (Sorry, off-topic) ;-)

Comment: IMHO you are exploiting `\typein`, that is, this contraption wasn't designed to be used like this, so little (or nothing) can be done to make it more friendly, basically because that wasn't the idea to start. `:)` I think the better approach to this scenario is using an script (say, with fancy input boxes powered by `zenity` or other windowing manager) and then generate a `.tex` file.

Comment: If i understand the question, this does not happen for me.

Comment: I think this depends on the console in the background, i.e. how the keys are interpreted?

Comment: _What ... is the capital of Assyria?_

Comment: @JosephWright: *I don't know that!*

Comment: @touhami and Christian Hupfer: that makes sense; I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and using the standard terminal. I wondered if it was a terminal-dependent thing, but I compared it to the results of using `input()` in Python and the results were different. But you're right, this could be very console-dependent.

Comment: @PauloCereda: that's definitely a good idea, and since this isn't the only user-friendliness concern I had, I'll likely have to end up doing that. But I didn't know this wasn't the intended use of `\typein`; what is it supposed to be used for?

Comment: @Arun: Oh I apologize for not clarifying what I meant! `\typein` was indeed conceived to allow user input (as user output provided by its counterpart `\typeout`), but it employs a basic reading. To make it more user-friendly, the whole thing should be wrapped in a helper macro which verifies the stream of captured tokens, but this could add another layer of complexity to the code's logic. I also suspect most of the reading capabilities are also bound to the used terminal, so we might expect different key handlings according to the context. >>>

Comment: @Arun: (ctd.) Sorry if my sentence sounded too harsh. You are certainly using it correctly, but the post-processing might be troublesome to say the least.

Comment: You might want to look at `rlwrap` http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, TeX programs only accept the backspace key as basic method for line editing when it comes for answering a prompt, be it caused by `\typein` (which is realized by reading from a non open stream) or by an error message.

Implementors *may* decide to link the program to a `readline` type library, but no current implementation I know of does it, because it would introduce too many dependencies.

Front-ends might allow line editing for input at prompts; I checked  TeXworks and TeXShop and they do. Of course, the front-end should be set up to call an interactive run of TeX (most call the engine with the `-interaction=nonstopmode` option, by default).

If Sir Galahad runs TeX (or any of the other typesetting engines) from the command line on a Unix system, you can install for him the utility [`rlwrap`](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/) so that he can prefix the call of TeX by `rlwrap`:

```
rlwrap pdflatex bridge
```

will allow Sir Galahad to use the standard line editing operations he uses for the shell (arrows, backspace or delete).