# How to perform calculations inside a .tex file in order to use the value in a function?

Tags: calculations

I'm trying to set a value to be used inside \vspace{} based on a value provided by a function which reads it from the keyboard. For example, if the provided value is 3, I would like for \vspace{} to be

```
\vspace{(3-1)0.6 cm}
```

What I've tried to do, without success, is

```
\documentclass[]{paper}
\usepackage{calc}

\newcommand{\titlelines}[1]{\def\@TitleLines{#1}}
\titlelines{3}
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{{\@TitleLines-1}*0.6}


\title{text \\ \vspace*{\mylength cm} more text}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Can you help me fix this code? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with your code, one of which is invisible. Because you did not use `\makeatletter`, your definition of `\titlelines` makes `\@` into a macro that eats `TitleLines` and spits out some number. Because you always follow `\@` by `TitleLines`, this doesn't cause an error.

You should parenthesize subexpressions for `calc` using parentheses, not braces. Also all dimensions need a unit. Also `calc` requires decimal numbers to be wrapped in the `\real` command:

```
\documentclass[]{paper}
\usepackage{calc}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\titlelines}[1]{\def\@TitleLines{#1}}
\titlelines{3}
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{(\@TitleLines cm-1cm)*\real{0.6}}
\makeatother


\title{text \\ \vspace*{\mylength} more text}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, because you have an `@`sign in your macro `\@TitleLines`, you must put the code that uses this macro between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` (unless it is in a class or package file). I would, however, recommend to use a macro without `@`.

Second, the `calc` package allows multiplication of a length only **after** the length: `\setlength{\mylength}{0.6cm * (\@TitleLines-1)}`.

And, third, round parentheses must be used in the expression.

So the code becomes:

```
\documentclass[]{paper}
\usepackage{calc}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\titlelines}[1]{\def\@TitleLines{#1}}
\titlelines{3}
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{0.6cm * (\@TitleLines-1)}
\makeatother

\title{text \\ \vspace*{\mylength} more text}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try to fix your attempt, but attempted to answer the implicit question another way. This works by defining the length you want on the compile command line. No `makeatletter` needed. It may or may not match your workflow.

If the input file is `cmddef.tex`  then compile with

```
pdflatex "\def\mylength{3 cm} \input{cmddef.tex}"
```

cmddef.tex:

```
\documentclass{paper}
%\newcommand{\mylength}{3 cm}

\title{text \\ \vspace*{\mylength{}} more text}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

The value of mylength is \mylength{}.
\end{document}
```

(Found at [Passing parameters to a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document))