# How do I refer to ouput-dir in a macro?

Tags: pdftex, output, directory

I build out-of-source with

```
pdflatex -output-dir=/foo
```

One of my macros generates temporary files in the working directory.

```
\immediate\write18{bash -c "some-command >outputfile"}
```

I want it to save them to the output directory instead.

How can I make my macro aware of the value given to the `-output-dir` command-line option?

Comment: There is no internal reference to the output directory, so you have to pass it via a macro: `pdflatex -output-directory=./foo "\def\outputdir{./foo}\input{myfile}"` and, in the document, you will have `\outputdir` available.

Comment: There really are no benefits to `-output-dir` it is much easier just to use the default output then move the generated files afterwards.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the benefit is that it doesn't add noise to my git repository

Comment: @spraff no the script or makefile or whatever you use to call pdflatex can move all generated files to whever you want to move them, at the end that is _much_ easier to configure than having pdftex write some files in a non standard place and then having to configure  other related programs to find them.

Comment: @spraff Why don't you switch to a temporary directory before running `pdflatex` and setup `TEXINPUTS` to find the files in your git repository directory?

Comment: I've tried both of those approaches and had problems. I'm baffled that a) latex was not originally designed to work well with relative paths, and b) the latex community thinks this is *normal* or even sensible. I think you guys have just gotten used to latex's way of doing things -- that doesn't mean it's the right way.

Comment: It's profoundly self-evident to me that the behaviour of a compiler should not depend on where the output goes. If you can't see the sanity of that I don't see any point arguing about it.

Comment: @spraff I guess for the more experienced users its as much about trying to help people avoid 'pitfalls' as saying 'this is how it should be'. As already noted in an answer, TeX files written as output are also input: this at least in part is reflective of the history of TeX (a program designed in the 1970s and with a workflow informed largely by working at the console). At least as it's currently implemented, `--output-dir` doesn't make the output directory an input directory (as far a TeX is concerned, all accessible files are 'here'). That's before you get to other tools ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in LaTeX the output directory is also an input directory (e.g. aux-file, toc etc) not only for pdflatex but also for other tools. In my experience it is in the long run much better not to use `--output-dir`. There is always one tool which doesn't find its input files. In git I simply use a sensible `.gitignore` file to avoid that the auxiliary files are committed.

Beside this: With luatex you can access the command line args as described in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18813/2388.

With pdflatex you can retrieve the `--output-dir` path in texlive  with the help of the currfile package. It needs the `--recorder`-option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[abspath]{currfile}
\begin{document}
\getabspath{test-utf8.log}
\theabsdir

\end{document}
```

[image]