# What's the correct way to define package options in expl3?

Tags: expl3, package-writing, key-value

For writing a package it's usually important to be able to define package options. Since the package I'm writing is in expl3 I wondered whether there's a l3ish way of defining key-value-package-options.

I know there's `l3keys` as part of `expl3`, but as far as I can tell, it does not evaluate options given to the package directly, but has to be called using a wrapper macro (can that be done automatically?).

Looking at the source code of `fontspec` it seems to utilize standard LaTeX2e's option processing facilities. Concluding from that I would use `kvoptions` for key-value-interfaces even for l3, although it creates l2 constructions such as `\newif`s.

On the other hand there's `siunitx` which uses the (poorly documented) package `l3keys2e` (@DavidCarlisle I do not want to reverse engineer) and the `l3keys` syntax for kv-option-processing. But is that a safe or recommended way? In my package I intend to use `l3keys` anyway.

To visualize what I want (a prototypical nonsense-MWE):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
    quack,% should evaluate to quack=true
    font=sffamily,% should set a font token list to sffamily
    logo=false,% should set a boolean to false
    size=3% should set an integer
]{mypack}
\begin{document}
    \quackfig
\end{document}
```

with `mypack.sty`:

```
\RequirePackage{expl3,xparse}
\ProvidesExplPackage{mypack}{2017-05-26}{v1.0}{Quack}

\RequirePackage{graphicx}

\bool_new:N \l__mypack_optkeys_quack_bool
\bool_set_true:N \l__mypack_optkeys_quack_bool
\tl_new:N \l__mypack_optkeys_font_tl
\bool_new:N \l__mypack_optkeys_logo_bool
\int_new:N \l__mypack_optkeys_size_int
\int_set:Nn \l__mypack_optkeys_size_int {10}

% Process options here
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\NewDocumentCommand{\quackfig}{}{
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \bool_if:NT \l__mypack_optkeys_quack_bool {
        \tl_if_eq:nnT {\l__mypack_optkeys_font} {sffamily} {\sffamily}
        Quack!
    }
    \bool_if:NT \l__mypack_optkeys_logo_bool {
        \includegraphics[height=\l__mypack_optkeys_size_int cm]{example-image}
    }
    \end{figure}
}
```

QUESTION: What is the recommended way for kv-option-processing with l3 and how would `mypack.sty` look then?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the lack of documentation in `l3keys2e`, perhaps on LaTeX-L or by direct mail?

Comment: @JosephWright Currently not, I'll try my best to remember when I have got some more free time. The main point however is that for me it's pretty unclear, which options specifically are processed by `\ProcessKeysPackageOptions` and `\ProcessKeysOptions` and whether there's a way to hide some options from those commands (only to set with a wrapper). But probably that's another question.

Comment: Side remark: I would avoid to declare to many package options. A setup `\usepackage{myquack}\myquacksetup{...}` is much more flexible and avoids option clash errors if the package is loaded more than once. (It also looks odd that you are passing an option to a class, but this perhaps only meant as example).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Without that passing the test document would not compile for me (that's absolutely not intended in the real example). Concerning the package options I would at least like to have the flexibility (and know how to do it, as I know with l2e). Whether that will be applied is open by now.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Irrespective of the key processor you are using, making use of keyval options for packages has two distinct parts:

- Defining the keys
- Processing the package option list using the keyval parser

What is crucial to understand here is that keyval package options are simply keys which have been defined at the point that the option list is processed.

From 2022-06-01, the LaTeX kernel has built-in support for keyval options handling; prior to that, very similar support was provided by `l3keys2e`. In either case, the approach uses `l3keys` to define options. This is done by defining the keys *then* processing the options

```
\providecommand \IfFormatAtLeastTF { \@ifl@t@r \fmtversion }
\ExplSyntaxOn
\keys_define:nn { mypkg }
  { pkgopt .tl_set:N = \l__mypkg_pkgopt_tl }
\IfFormatAtLeastTF { 2022-06-01 }
  { \ProcessKeyOptions }
  {
    \RequirePackage { l3keys2e }
    \ProcessKeysOptions { mypkg }
  }
\ProcessKeysOptions { mypkg } % Parses the option list
\keys_define:nn { mypkg }
  { notpkgopt .tl_set:N = \l__mypkg_notopt_tl }
```

The above will define one keyval option for the package: `pkgopt`, which will store the given value in the `\l__mypkg_pkgopt_tl`. The second key `notpkgopt` is defined *after* keyval processing so is not available to `\ProcessKey(s)Options`: it is therefore *not a package option*.

If one wishes to define all keys 'up front' but only make some available as options, the usual approach would be to use multiple paths, say `mypkg / pkgopts` and `mypkg / otheropts`.

One common use for this approach is to disable an option which is strictly load-time only. That is built-in for the kernel from 2022-06-01

```
\keys_define:nn { mypkg }
  {
    pkgopt .tl_set:N = \l__mypkg_pkgopt_tl ,
    pkgopt .usage:n. = load-only
  }
```

As noted in a comment, it is usually best to favour a setup command (`\mypkgsetup`) which can be used *after* loading, unless the options directly affect package loading set up, *etc.*

Comment: It seems that today you can also use `\ProcessKeyOptions [ mypkg ]` without loading `l3keys2e`.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Updated for the newer kerenel