# Columns of questions without interruptions for a test with multiple choice

Tags: expl3, xparse

I have the file `sebmcq.sty` created by the excellent users *Florent Rougon, Enrico Gregorio* to generate a multiple choice questions with answers.

```
% sebmcq.sty --- Multiple choice questions. Can print questions and proposed
%                answers in a random order. Optionally show the correct
%                answers.
%
% See <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529060/73317> for more information.
%
% Copyright (C) 2020  Florent Rougon, Enrico Gregorio
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3 can be found in the LICENSE file present in this
% distribution.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work is Florent Rougon.
%
% This work consists of only one file: sebmcq.sty.
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}
\RequirePackage{amssymb,bbding}        % for the \checkmark
\ProvidesExplPackage{sebmcq}{2020-03-14}{0.6}
  {Multiple choice questions}

\str_new:N \l_questionnaire_env_str
\seq_new:N \l__sebmcq_questions_seq
\tl_new:N \l__sebmcq_answers_tl
\tl_new:N \l__sebmcq_correctness_code_tl
\tl_new:N \l__sebmcq_answer_tl
\bool_new:N \l_sebmcq_shuffle_questions_bool
\bool_new:N \l_sebmcq_shuffle_answers_bool
\bool_new:N \l_sebmcq_show_correct_answers_bool
\bool_new:N \l__sebmcq_has_correct_answer_bool    % parsing stage
\bool_new:N \l__sebmcq_correct_answer_marked_bool % rendering stage
\skip_new:N \l_sebmcq_after_answer_num_skip        % horizontal skip

\msg_new:nnn { sebmcq } { invalid-answer-opt-arg }
  { Invalid~input~inside~brackets~before~answer:~'#1'. }

\msg_new:nnn { sebmcq } { empty-answer-opt-arg }
  { Empty~input~inside~brackets~before~answer. }

\msg_new:nnn { sebmcq } { question-cmd-used-outside-of-questionnaire-env }
  { \question command~used~outside~of~questionnaire~environment. }

% This is assumed to be illegal
\msg_new:nnn { sebmcq } { several-correct-answers }
  { Several~answers~have~been~marked~as~correct~for~a~question. }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_read_answer_with_optarg:wn [#1]#2
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1}
      { \msg_error:nn { sebmcq } { empty-answer-opt-arg } }
      {
        \str_if_in:nnTF { xX } {#1}
          {
            \bool_if:NTF \l__sebmcq_has_correct_answer_bool
              { \msg_error:nn { sebmcq } { several-correct-answers } }
              {
                \bool_set_true:N \l__sebmcq_has_correct_answer_bool
                \tl_put_right:Nn \l__sebmcq_answers_tl
                  { { { \correct } {#2} } }
              }
          }
          { \msg_error:nnn { sebmcq } { invalid-answer-opt-arg } {#1} }
      }
    \__sebmcq_read_answers:w % recurse
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_read_answer_without_optarg:n #1
  {
    % Incorrect answer
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__sebmcq_answers_tl { { { } {#1} } }
    \__sebmcq_read_answers:w % recurse
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_read_answers:w
  {
    \peek_meaning_ignore_spaces:NTF \q_stop
      { \use_none:n }
      {
        \peek_meaning_ignore_spaces:NTF [
          { \__sebmcq_read_answer_with_optarg:wn }
          { \__sebmcq_read_answer_without_optarg:n }
      }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_maybe_mark_correct_answer:
  {
    % Little trick in the boolean expression: this allows us to automatically
    % mark the freeform answer as correct if none of the explicitly given
    % answers was declared as correct.
    \bool_if:nT
      {
          \bool_if_p:N \l_sebmcq_show_correct_answers_bool &&
        ! \bool_if_p:N \l__sebmcq_correct_answer_marked_bool
      }
      {
        \makebox[0pt][r] {\CheckmarkBold \skip_horizontal:n { 0.5em } }
        % No other answer will be marked as correct for this question.
        \bool_set_true:N \l__sebmcq_correct_answer_marked_bool
      }
  }

% Default function for formatting the question number
\cs_new_protected:Npn \sebmcq_format_question_number_default:n #1
  {
    \fbox { \makebox[\height]{ \int_to_Alph:n {#1} } }
  }

% #1: empty means the answer is incorrect
% #2: answer number
% #3: answer text
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_print_proposed_answer:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nF {#1} { \__sebmcq_maybe_mark_correct_answer: }
    \__sebmcq_format_question_number:n {#2}
    \skip_horizontal:n { \l_sebmcq_after_answer_num_skip } {#3} \\[0.5ex]
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__sebmcq_print_proposed_answer:nnn { VnV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__sebmcq_format_question_number:n { x }

% Based on egreg's code: <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/519972/73317>
% #1: question text; #2: proposed answers
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_read_question:nn #1#2
  {
    \tl_clear:N \l__sebmcq_answers_tl
    \bool_set_false:N \l__sebmcq_has_correct_answer_bool
    \__sebmcq_read_answers:w #2 \q_stop
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__sebmcq_questions_seq
      {
        { \exp_not:n {#1} }                                    % { question }
        { \exp_not:n \exp_after:wN { \l__sebmcq_answers_tl } } % { answers }
      }
  }

\seq_new:N \l__sebmcq_oq_answers_seq

% #1: question
% #2: answers, each of which being of the form
% { { \correct or empty } { answer text } }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_output_question:nn #1#2
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__sebmcq_oq_answers_seq { } {#2}
    \bool_if:NT \l_sebmcq_shuffle_answers_bool
      { \seq_shuffle:N \l__sebmcq_oq_answers_seq }

    \item {#1} \\[2ex]          % question text

    \bool_set_false:N \l__sebmcq_correct_answer_marked_bool
    \seq_indexed_map_inline:Nn \l__sebmcq_oq_answers_seq
      {
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { } {##2}
        \seq_pop_left:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l__sebmcq_correctness_code_tl
        \seq_pop_left:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l__sebmcq_answer_tl
        \__sebmcq_print_proposed_answer:VnV
          \l__sebmcq_correctness_code_tl {##1}
          \l__sebmcq_answer_tl
      }

    \__sebmcq_maybe_mark_correct_answer:
    \__sebmcq_format_question_number:x
      { \int_eval:n { \seq_count:N \l__sebmcq_oq_answers_seq + 1 } }
    \skip_horizontal:n { \l_sebmcq_after_answer_num_skip }
    \hbox_to_wd:nn { 9em } { \hrulefill }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_output_question:n #1
  { \__sebmcq_output_question:nn #1 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_output_questionnaire:
  {
    \bool_if:NT \l_sebmcq_shuffle_questions_bool
      { \seq_shuffle:N \l__sebmcq_questions_seq }
    % I didn't use \seq_map_inline:Nn here because it would fail with l3kernel
    % older than 2020-03-14 (this is due to a bug in \seq_shuffle:N
    % <https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/687>, fixed in this commit:
    % <https://github.com/latex3/latex3/commit/42c70c63fd83324c5792dd14538a39dd7e388a55>).
    \seq_map_function:NN \l__sebmcq_questions_seq \__sebmcq_output_question:n
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \question { }
  {
    \msg_error:nn { sebmcq } { question-cmd-used-outside-of-questionnaire-env }
  }

\NewDocumentEnvironment { questionnaire } { O{} }
  {
    \keys_set:nn { sebmcq } {#1}
    \cs_set_eq:NN \question \__sebmcq_read_question:nn
    \tl_clear:N \l__sebmcq_questions_seq
    \use:c { \str_use:N \l_questionnaire_env_str }
  }
  {
    \__sebmcq_output_questionnaire:
    \use:c { end \str_use:N \l_questionnaire_env_str }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \ShowCorrectAnswers { }
 {
   \bool_set_true:N \l_sebmcq_show_correct_answers_bool
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \HideCorrectAnswers { }
 {
   \bool_set_false:N \l_sebmcq_show_correct_answers_bool
 }

% Set the default question number formatter
\cs_new_eq:NN \__sebmcq_format_question_number:n
              \sebmcq_format_question_number_default:n

\keys_define:nn { sebmcq }
  {
    after-answer-num-skip .skip_set:N = \l_sebmcq_after_answer_num_skip ,
    after-answer-num-skip .value_required:n = true,
    after-answer-num-skip .initial:n = { 0.9em },
    %
    answer-number-format  .code:n = {
      \cs_set_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_format_question_number:n ##1 {#1} },
    answer-number-format  .value_required:n = true,
    %
    questionnaire-env     .code:n = {
      \str_set:Nn \l_questionnaire_env_str {#1} },
    questionnaire-env     .value_required:n = true,
    questionnaire-env     .initial:n = { enumerate },
    %
    show-correct-answers  .bool_set:N = \l_sebmcq_show_correct_answers_bool,
    show-correct-answers  .initial:n = { false },
    show-correct-answers  .default:n = { true },
    %
    shuffle-questions     .bool_set:N = \l_sebmcq_shuffle_questions_bool,
    shuffle-questions     .initial:n = { false },
    shuffle-questions     .default:n = { true },
    %
    shuffle-answers       .bool_set:N = \l_sebmcq_shuffle_answers_bool,
    shuffle-answers       .initial:n = { false },
    shuffle-answers       .default:n = { true },
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \sebmcqSetup { m }
  {
    \keys_set:nn { sebmcq } {#1}
  }

% Process LaTeX2e-style package options. This uses l3keys2e, see
% <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/371754/73317> for explanations.
\ProcessKeysPackageOptions { sebmcq }

\endinput
```

When I create a multiple choice questions (for example) the first column have the question nr. 6 in the first column and the **A, B, C, D and E** in the second column.

> How is it possible to modify the code to produce questions that do not have column breaks between the question and the various choices?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[leqno,12pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
%\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx,multicol,array}
\graphicspath{ {img/} }

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{landscape,a3paper,
          tmargin=0.6in,bmargin=0.35in,hmargin=0.35in}
\usepackage[italic,basic, default mathsizes]{mathastext}
\MTlettershape{sl}\Mathastext

\makeatletter
\@for\@tempa:=a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z\do{%
\MTsetmathskips{\@tempa}{0mu}{0.5mu}}%
\@for\@tempa:=A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z\do{%
\MTsetmathskips{\@tempa}{0mu}{0.5mu}}%
\makeatother
\usepackage{expl3}             % for \int_to_alph:n
\usepackage{xparse}                       % only for the 'test' environment
\usepackage[shuffle-questions, shuffle-answers]{sebmcq}
\pagestyle{empty}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment { test } { m +b }
  { \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { #2 \clearpage } }
  { }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\ShowCorrectAnswers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{16pt}
\lhead{\sffamily\bfseries \textsc{ }}
\chead{\sffamily\bfseries a.s. 2021--2022}
\rhead{\sffamily\bfseries Test }
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{icomma}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\large
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{questionnaire}

\question{In notazione scientifica, il numero 0.00364
diventa}
{
    {$3.64 \times 10^3$.}
    {$3.64 \times 10^2$.}
    {$3.64 \times 10^{-2}$.}
     [X]{$3.64 \times 10^{-3}$.}
}

\question{Un volume di 10 cm$^3$ è uguale a:}
{
    {0.1 dm$^3$.}
    {100 mm$^3$.}
   [X]{10000 mm$^3$.}
    {0.00001 mm$^3$.}
}

\question{Quale unità SI è più appropriata per
misurare lo spessore di un foglio di carta?}
{
    {il metro.}
    [X]{il millimetro.}
   {il decimetro.}
    {il chilometro.}
}

\question{Sono grandezze fondamentali nel Sistema
Internazionale \ldots}
{
    {volume, densità e peso specifico.}
    {massa e densità.}
   [X]{temperatura e massa.}
    {volume e tempo.}
}


\question{Una grandezza fisica derivata \ldots }
{
    {ha un'unità di misura definita dal rapporto tra le unità di misura di grandezze fondamentali.}
    {non ha unità di misura.}
   [X]{è definita attraverso una relazione con le grandezze fondamentali.}
    {ha un'unità di misura definita dal prodotto delle unità di misura di grandezze fondamentali.}
}


\question{Quante sono le cifre significative nel
numero $2.50 \times 10^4$?}
{
    {due.}
    {quattro.}
   [X]{tre.}
    {sette.}
}


\question{Quale grandezza si può misurare con una bilancia a bracci uguali?}
{
    {La quantità di sostanza.}
    {Il peso.}
   [X]{La massa.}
    {La forza.}
}


\question{L'unità di misura della velocità nel S.I. è:}
{
    {km/h.}
    {km/s.}
   [X]{m/s.}
    {cm/s.}
}


\question{Quanti zeri sono significativi nel numero 40 400 302?}
{
    {uno.}
    {due.}
   [X]{quattro.}
    {tre.}
}


\question{La massa di un corpo \ldots}
{
    {varia al variare della temperatura del corpo.}
    {varia al variare della posizione del corpo.}
   [X]{è un valore costante del corpo.}
    {varia al variare della distanza del corpo dalla
Terra.}
}




\end{questionnaire}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to disallow a page/column break after the question text, which is achieved by replacing

```
    \item {#1} \\[2ex]          % question text
```

with

```
    \item {#1} \\*[2ex]          % question text
```

I had to modify slightly the geometry to `bmargin=0.4in` in order to reproduce the issue.

Other changes:

```
    questionnaire-env     .code:n = {
      \str_set:Nn \l_questionnaire_env_str {#1} },
```

should be

```
    questionnaire-env     .str_set:N = \l_questionnaire_env_str,
```

and

```
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__sebmcq_questions_seq
      {
        { \exp_not:n {#1} }                                    % { question }
        { \exp_not:n \exp_after:wN { \l__sebmcq_answers_tl } } % { answers }
      }
```

should be

```
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__sebmcq_questions_seq
      {
        { \exp_not:n {#1} }                  % { question }
        { \exp_not:V \l__sebmcq_answers_tl } % { answers }
      }
```

By the way, I have no bearing with that style file. Maybe I suggested something, but definitely didn't write all that code.

Here's an edited version of the `.sty` file

```
% sebmcq.sty --- Multiple choice questions. Can print questions and proposed
%                answers in a random order. Optionally show the correct
%                answers.
%
% See <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529060/73317> for more information.
%
% Copyright (C) 2020  Florent Rougon, Enrico Gregorio
%%%
%%% Modified by egreg
%%%
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3 can be found in the LICENSE file present in this
% distribution.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work is Florent Rougon.
%
% This work consists of only one file: sebmcq.sty.
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}
\RequirePackage{amssymb,bbding}        % for the \checkmark
\ProvidesExplPackage{sebmcq}{2020-03-14}{0.6}
  {Multiple choice questions}

\str_new:N \l_questionnaire_env_str
\seq_new:N \l__sebmcq_questions_seq
\tl_new:N \l__sebmcq_answers_tl
\tl_new:N \l__sebmcq_correctness_code_tl
\tl_new:N \l__sebmcq_answer_tl
\bool_new:N \l_sebmcq_shuffle_questions_bool
\bool_new:N \l_sebmcq_shuffle_answers_bool
\bool_new:N \l_sebmcq_show_correct_answers_bool
\bool_new:N \l__sebmcq_has_correct_answer_bool    % parsing stage
\bool_new:N \l__sebmcq_correct_answer_marked_bool % rendering stage
\skip_new:N \l_sebmcq_after_answer_num_skip        % horizontal skip

\msg_new:nnn { sebmcq } { invalid-answer-opt-arg }
  { Invalid~input~inside~brackets~before~answer:~'#1'. }

\msg_new:nnn { sebmcq } { empty-answer-opt-arg }
  { Empty~input~inside~brackets~before~answer. }

\msg_new:nnn { sebmcq } { question-cmd-used-outside-of-questionnaire-env }
  { \question command~used~outside~of~questionnaire~environment. }

% This is assumed to be illegal
\msg_new:nnn { sebmcq } { several-correct-answers }
  { Several~answers~have~been~marked~as~correct~for~a~question. }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_read_answer_with_optarg:wn [#1]#2
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1}
      { \msg_error:nn { sebmcq } { empty-answer-opt-arg } }
      {
        \str_if_in:nnTF { xX } {#1}
          {
            \bool_if:NTF \l__sebmcq_has_correct_answer_bool
              { \msg_error:nn { sebmcq } { several-correct-answers } }
              {
                \bool_set_true:N \l__sebmcq_has_correct_answer_bool
                \tl_put_right:Nn \l__sebmcq_answers_tl
                  { { { \correct } {#2} } }
              }
          }
          { \msg_error:nnn { sebmcq } { invalid-answer-opt-arg } {#1} }
      }
    \__sebmcq_read_answers:w % recurse
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_read_answer_without_optarg:n #1
  {
    % Incorrect answer
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__sebmcq_answers_tl { { { } {#1} } }
    \__sebmcq_read_answers:w % recurse
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_read_answers:w
  {
    \peek_meaning_ignore_spaces:NTF \q_stop
      { \use_none:n }
      {
        \peek_meaning_ignore_spaces:NTF [
          { \__sebmcq_read_answer_with_optarg:wn }
          { \__sebmcq_read_answer_without_optarg:n }
      }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_maybe_mark_correct_answer:
  {
    % Little trick in the boolean expression: this allows us to automatically
    % mark the freeform answer as correct if none of the explicitly given
    % answers was declared as correct.
    \bool_if:nT
      {
          \bool_if_p:N \l_sebmcq_show_correct_answers_bool &&
        ! \bool_if_p:N \l__sebmcq_correct_answer_marked_bool
      }
      {
        \makebox[0pt][r] {\CheckmarkBold \skip_horizontal:n { 0.5em } }
        % No other answer will be marked as correct for this question.
        \bool_set_true:N \l__sebmcq_correct_answer_marked_bool
      }
  }

% Default function for formatting the question number
\cs_new_protected:Npn \sebmcq_format_question_number_default:n #1
  {
    \fbox { \makebox[\height]{ \int_to_Alph:n {#1} } }
  }

% #1: empty means the answer is incorrect
% #2: answer number
% #3: answer text
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_print_proposed_answer:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nF {#1} { \__sebmcq_maybe_mark_correct_answer: }
    \__sebmcq_format_question_number:n {#2}
    \skip_horizontal:n { \l_sebmcq_after_answer_num_skip } {#3} \\[0.5ex]
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__sebmcq_print_proposed_answer:nnn { VnV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__sebmcq_format_question_number:n { x }

% Based on egreg's code: <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/519972/73317>
% #1: question text; #2: proposed answers
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_read_question:nn #1#2
  {
    \tl_clear:N \l__sebmcq_answers_tl
    \bool_set_false:N \l__sebmcq_has_correct_answer_bool
    \__sebmcq_read_answers:w #2 \q_stop
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__sebmcq_questions_seq
      {
        { \exp_not:n {#1} }                  % { question }
        { \exp_not:V \l__sebmcq_answers_tl } % { answers }
      }
  }

\seq_new:N \l__sebmcq_oq_answers_seq

% #1: question
% #2: answers, each of which being of the form
% { { \correct or empty } { answer text } }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_output_question:nn #1#2
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__sebmcq_oq_answers_seq { } {#2}
    \bool_if:NT \l_sebmcq_shuffle_answers_bool
      { \seq_shuffle:N \l__sebmcq_oq_answers_seq }

    \item {#1} \\*[2ex]          % question text

    \bool_set_false:N \l__sebmcq_correct_answer_marked_bool
    \seq_indexed_map_inline:Nn \l__sebmcq_oq_answers_seq
      {
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { } {##2}
        \seq_pop_left:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l__sebmcq_correctness_code_tl
        \seq_pop_left:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l__sebmcq_answer_tl
        \__sebmcq_print_proposed_answer:VnV
          \l__sebmcq_correctness_code_tl {##1}
          \l__sebmcq_answer_tl
      }

    \__sebmcq_maybe_mark_correct_answer:
    \__sebmcq_format_question_number:x
      { \int_eval:n { \seq_count:N \l__sebmcq_oq_answers_seq + 1 } }
    \skip_horizontal:n { \l_sebmcq_after_answer_num_skip }
    \hbox_to_wd:nn { 9em } { \hrulefill }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_output_question:n #1
  { \__sebmcq_output_question:nn #1 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_output_questionnaire:
  {
    \bool_if:NT \l_sebmcq_shuffle_questions_bool
      { \seq_shuffle:N \l__sebmcq_questions_seq }
    % I didn't use \seq_map_inline:Nn here because it would fail with l3kernel
    % older than 2020-03-14 (this is due to a bug in \seq_shuffle:N
    % <https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/687>, fixed in this commit:
    % <https://github.com/latex3/latex3/commit/42c70c63fd83324c5792dd14538a39dd7e388a55>).
    \seq_map_function:NN \l__sebmcq_questions_seq \__sebmcq_output_question:n
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \question { }
  {
    \msg_error:nn { sebmcq } { question-cmd-used-outside-of-questionnaire-env }
  }

\NewDocumentEnvironment { questionnaire } { O{} }
  {
    \keys_set:nn { sebmcq } {#1}
    \cs_set_eq:NN \question \__sebmcq_read_question:nn
    \tl_clear:N \l__sebmcq_questions_seq
    \use:c { \str_use:N \l_questionnaire_env_str }
  }
  {
    \__sebmcq_output_questionnaire:
    \use:c { end \str_use:N \l_questionnaire_env_str }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \ShowCorrectAnswers { }
 {
   \bool_set_true:N \l_sebmcq_show_correct_answers_bool
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \HideCorrectAnswers { }
 {
   \bool_set_false:N \l_sebmcq_show_correct_answers_bool
 }

% Set the default question number formatter
\cs_new_eq:NN \__sebmcq_format_question_number:n
              \sebmcq_format_question_number_default:n

\keys_define:nn { sebmcq }
  {
    after-answer-num-skip .skip_set:N = \l_sebmcq_after_answer_num_skip ,
    after-answer-num-skip .value_required:n = true,
    after-answer-num-skip .initial:n = { 0.9em },
    %
    answer-number-format  .code:n = {
      \cs_set_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_format_question_number:n ##1 {#1} },
    answer-number-format  .value_required:n = true,
    %
    questionnaire-env     .str_set:N = \l_questionnaire_env_str,
    questionnaire-env     .value_required:n = true,
    questionnaire-env     .initial:n = { enumerate },
    %
    show-correct-answers  .bool_set:N = \l_sebmcq_show_correct_answers_bool,
    show-correct-answers  .initial:n = { false },
    show-correct-answers  .default:n = { true },
    %
    shuffle-questions     .bool_set:N = \l_sebmcq_shuffle_questions_bool,
    shuffle-questions     .initial:n = { false },
    shuffle-questions     .default:n = { true },
    %
    shuffle-answers       .bool_set:N = \l_sebmcq_shuffle_answers_bool,
    shuffle-answers       .initial:n = { false },
    shuffle-answers       .default:n = { true },
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \sebmcqSetup { m }
  {
    \keys_set:nn { sebmcq } {#1}
  }

% Process LaTeX2e-style package options. This uses l3keys2e, see
% <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/371754/73317> for explanations.
\ProcessKeysPackageOptions { sebmcq }

\endinput
```

Comment: Kindest Prof. :-) no no...it was the very kind @frougon that have written all if I remember well. Hence....what is the complete and definitive sebmcq.sty with all the changes? :-)))))) I got out of the hospital yesterday but my head is whirring like in a blender. I went back to school this morning despite the doctors advice to the contrary.

Comment: I have done all your suggestion but I have ! File ended while scanning definition of \__sebmcq_read_question:nn.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.34 

      
?  like as mistake. :-(

Comment: @Sebastiano I added a full version of the edited `.sty`.

Comment: Grazieeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee