How to put centered figures in \question{} using TikZ and \includegraphics without mistakes
Considering the .sty file of Florent Rougon and Enrico Gregorio
% sebmcq.sty --- Multiple choice questions. Can print questions and proposed
%                answers in a random order. Optionally show the correct
%                answers.
%
% See <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/529060/73317> for more information.
%
% Copyright (C) 2020  Florent Rougon, Enrico Gregorio
%%%
%%% Modified by egreg
%%%
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
% The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3 can be found in the LICENSE file present in this
% distribution.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status `maintained'.
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work is Florent Rougon.
%
% This work consists of only one file: sebmcq.sty.
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}
\RequirePackage{amssymb,bbding}        % for the \checkmark
\ProvidesExplPackage{sebmcq}{2020-03-14}{0.6}
  {Multiple choice questions}

\str_new:N \l_questionnaire_env_str
\seq_new:N \l__sebmcq_questions_seq
\tl_new:N \l__sebmcq_answers_tl
\tl_new:N \l__sebmcq_correctness_code_tl
\tl_new:N \l__sebmcq_answer_tl
\bool_new:N \l_sebmcq_shuffle_questions_bool
\bool_new:N \l_sebmcq_shuffle_answers_bool
\bool_new:N \l_sebmcq_show_correct_answers_bool
\bool_new:N \l__sebmcq_has_correct_answer_bool    % parsing stage
\bool_new:N \l__sebmcq_correct_answer_marked_bool % rendering stage
\skip_new:N \l_sebmcq_after_answer_num_skip        % horizontal skip

\msg_new:nnn { sebmcq } { invalid-answer-opt-arg }
  { Invalid~input~inside~brackets~before~answer:~'#1'. }

\msg_new:nnn { sebmcq } { empty-answer-opt-arg }
  { Empty~input~inside~brackets~before~answer. }

\msg_new:nnn { sebmcq } { question-cmd-used-outside-of-questionnaire-env }
  { \question command~used~outside~of~questionnaire~environment. }

% This is assumed to be illegal
\msg_new:nnn { sebmcq } { several-correct-answers }
  { Several~answers~have~been~marked~as~correct~for~a~question. }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_read_answer_with_optarg:wn [#1]#2
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nTF {#1}
      { \msg_error:nn { sebmcq } { empty-answer-opt-arg } }
      {
        \str_if_in:nnTF { xX } {#1}
          {
            \bool_if:NTF \l__sebmcq_has_correct_answer_bool
              { \msg_error:nn { sebmcq } { several-correct-answers } }
              {
                \bool_set_true:N \l__sebmcq_has_correct_answer_bool
                \tl_put_right:Nn \l__sebmcq_answers_tl
                  { { { \correct } {#2} } }
              }
          }
          { \msg_error:nnn { sebmcq } { invalid-answer-opt-arg } {#1} }
      }
    \__sebmcq_read_answers:w % recurse
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_read_answer_without_optarg:n #1
  {
    % Incorrect answer
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__sebmcq_answers_tl { { { } {#1} } }
    \__sebmcq_read_answers:w % recurse
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_read_answers:w
  {
    \peek_meaning_ignore_spaces:NTF \q_stop
      { \use_none:n }
      {
        \peek_meaning_ignore_spaces:NTF [
          { \__sebmcq_read_answer_with_optarg:wn }
          { \__sebmcq_read_answer_without_optarg:n }
      }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_maybe_mark_correct_answer:
  {
    % Little trick in the boolean expression: this allows us to automatically
    % mark the freeform answer as correct if none of the explicitly given
    % answers was declared as correct.
    \bool_if:nT
      {
          \bool_if_p:N \l_sebmcq_show_correct_answers_bool &&
        ! \bool_if_p:N \l__sebmcq_correct_answer_marked_bool
      }
      {
        \makebox[0pt][r] {\CheckmarkBold \skip_horizontal:n { 0.5em } }
        % No other answer will be marked as correct for this question.
        \bool_set_true:N \l__sebmcq_correct_answer_marked_bool
      }
  }

% Default function for formatting the question number
\cs_new_protected:Npn \sebmcq_format_question_number_default:n #1
  {
    \fbox { \makebox[\height]{ \int_to_Alph:n {#1} } }
  }

% #1: empty means the answer is incorrect
% #2: answer number
% #3: answer text
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_print_proposed_answer:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nF {#1} { \__sebmcq_maybe_mark_correct_answer: }
    \__sebmcq_format_question_number:n {#2}
    \skip_horizontal:n { \l_sebmcq_after_answer_num_skip } {#3} \\[0.5ex]
  }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__sebmcq_print_proposed_answer:nnn { VnV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__sebmcq_format_question_number:n { x }

% Based on egreg's code: <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/519972/73317>
% #1: question text; #2: proposed answers
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_read_question:nn #1#2
  {
    \tl_clear:N \l__sebmcq_answers_tl
    \bool_set_false:N \l__sebmcq_has_correct_answer_bool
    \__sebmcq_read_answers:w #2 \q_stop
    \seq_put_right:Nx \l__sebmcq_questions_seq
      {
        { \exp_not:n {#1} }                  % { question }
        { \exp_not:V \l__sebmcq_answers_tl } % { answers }
      }
  }

\seq_new:N \l__sebmcq_oq_answers_seq

% #1: question
% #2: answers, each of which being of the form
% { { \correct or empty } { answer text } }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_output_question:nn #1#2
  {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__sebmcq_oq_answers_seq { } {#2}
    \bool_if:NT \l_sebmcq_shuffle_answers_bool
      { \seq_shuffle:N \l__sebmcq_oq_answers_seq }

    \item {#1} \\*[2ex]          % question text

    \bool_set_false:N \l__sebmcq_correct_answer_marked_bool
    \seq_indexed_map_inline:Nn \l__sebmcq_oq_answers_seq
      {
        \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { } {##2}
        \seq_pop_left:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l__sebmcq_correctness_code_tl
        \seq_pop_left:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l__sebmcq_answer_tl
        \__sebmcq_print_proposed_answer:VnV
          \l__sebmcq_correctness_code_tl {##1}
          \l__sebmcq_answer_tl
      }

    \__sebmcq_maybe_mark_correct_answer:
    \__sebmcq_format_question_number:x
      { \int_eval:n { \seq_count:N \l__sebmcq_oq_answers_seq + 1 } }
    \skip_horizontal:n { \l_sebmcq_after_answer_num_skip }
    \hbox_to_wd:nn { 9em } { \hrulefill }
  }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_output_question:n #1
  { \__sebmcq_output_question:nn #1 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_output_questionnaire:
  {
    \bool_if:NT \l_sebmcq_shuffle_questions_bool
      { \seq_shuffle:N \l__sebmcq_questions_seq }
    % I didn't use \seq_map_inline:Nn here because it would fail with l3kernel
    % older than 2020-03-14 (this is due to a bug in \seq_shuffle:N
    % <https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/687>, fixed in this commit:
    % <https://github.com/latex3/latex3/commit/42c70c63fd83324c5792dd14538a39dd7e388a55>).
    \seq_map_function:NN \l__sebmcq_questions_seq \__sebmcq_output_question:n
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \question { }
  {
    \msg_error:nn { sebmcq } { question-cmd-used-outside-of-questionnaire-env }
  }

\NewDocumentEnvironment { questionnaire } { O{} }
  {
    \keys_set:nn { sebmcq } {#1}
    \cs_set_eq:NN \question \__sebmcq_read_question:nn
    \tl_clear:N \l__sebmcq_questions_seq
    \use:c { \str_use:N \l_questionnaire_env_str }
  }
  {
    \__sebmcq_output_questionnaire:
    \use:c { end \str_use:N \l_questionnaire_env_str }
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \ShowCorrectAnswers { }
 {
   \bool_set_true:N \l_sebmcq_show_correct_answers_bool
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \HideCorrectAnswers { }
 {
   \bool_set_false:N \l_sebmcq_show_correct_answers_bool
 }

% Set the default question number formatter
\cs_new_eq:NN \__sebmcq_format_question_number:n
              \sebmcq_format_question_number_default:n

\keys_define:nn { sebmcq }
  {
    after-answer-num-skip .skip_set:N = \l_sebmcq_after_answer_num_skip ,
    after-answer-num-skip .value_required:n = true,
    after-answer-num-skip .initial:n = { 0.9em },
    %
    answer-number-format  .code:n = {
      \cs_set_protected:Npn \__sebmcq_format_question_number:n ##1 {#1} },
    answer-number-format  .value_required:n = true,
    %
    questionnaire-env     .str_set:N = \l_questionnaire_env_str,
    questionnaire-env     .value_required:n = true,
    questionnaire-env     .initial:n = { enumerate },
    %
    show-correct-answers  .bool_set:N = \l_sebmcq_show_correct_answers_bool,
    show-correct-answers  .initial:n = { false },
    show-correct-answers  .default:n = { true },
    %
    shuffle-questions     .bool_set:N = \l_sebmcq_shuffle_questions_bool,
    shuffle-questions     .initial:n = { false },
    shuffle-questions     .default:n = { true },
    %
    shuffle-answers       .bool_set:N = \l_sebmcq_shuffle_answers_bool,
    shuffle-answers       .initial:n = { false },
    shuffle-answers       .default:n = { true },
  }

\NewDocumentCommand \sebmcqSetup { m }
  {
    \keys_set:nn { sebmcq } {#1}
  }

% Process LaTeX2e-style package options. This uses l3keys2e, see
% <https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/371754/73317> for explanations.
\ProcessKeysPackageOptions { sebmcq }

\endinput

I am not able to put into \question{} a centered code done with TiKZ (without mistakes) or with 1 or more centered figures with \includeimages or 1 or more centered figures created with TikZ.
\question{La trasformazione di Galileo delle velocità è valida:}
{
    [X]{in tutti i sistemi di riferimento inerziali.}
    {in tutti i sistemi di riferimento.}
    {in tutti i sistemi di riferimento non inerziali.}
     {quando gli oggetti si muovono con accelerazione costante.}
}

My .tex code is:
\documentclass[leqno,12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,multicol}
\usepackage{expl3}             % for \int_to_alph:n
\usepackage{xparse}           % only for the 'test' environment
\usepackage[shuffle-questions, shuffle-answers]{sebmcq}
\pagestyle{empty}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment { test } { m +b }
  { \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { #2 \clearpage } }
  { }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\ShowCorrectAnswers
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots} % For plotting
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} % Set compatibility for pgfplots
\usetikzlibrary{arrows} % TikZ library for arrows
\begin{document}
\large
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{questionnaire}
\question{La trasformazione di Galileo delle velocità è valida:}
{
    [X]{in tutti i sistemi di riferimento inerziali.}
    {in tutti i sistemi di riferimento.}
    {in tutti i sistemi di riferimento non inerziali.}
    {quando gli oggetti si muovono con accelerazione costante.}
}
\end{questionnaire}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}

Related:

Automatically shake questions and answers for a test created with LaTeX after the compilation
Multiple choice questions with proposed answers in random order — addition of automatic correction (cross mark)


that's a far from minimal example but it finally has essentially empty content so what do you expect it to produce? also you should not be loading expl3 or xparse unless you have an old latex format, please edit your question to have a minimal example and say what output you expect

If you are asking about centering figures why is most of your example code setting up math fonts  \DeclareMathSymbol {\mst@k}{\mathalpha}{fourierletters}{k}` ????

@DavidCarlisle Done! for your 2nd comment it was in a old file.

The package clearly is not expecting vertical display material in the answers, but as always in such cases you can give it a parbox to hold the centred display.

\documentclass[leqno,12pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,multicol}
\usepackage{expl3}             % for \int_to_alph:n
\usepackage{xparse}           % only for the 'test' environment
\usepackage[shuffle-questions, shuffle-answers]{sebmcq}
\pagestyle{empty}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentEnvironment { test } { m +b }
  { \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { #2 \clearpage } }
  { }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\ShowCorrectAnswers
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots} % For plotting
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} % Set compatibility for pgfplots
\usetikzlibrary{arrows} % TikZ library for arrows
\begin{document}
\large
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{questionnaire}
  \question{\parbox[t]{\linewidth}{
      La trasformazione di Galileo delle velocità è valida:
       \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[height=2em]{example-image}
      \end{center}}
}
{
    [X]{in tutti i sistemi di riferimento inerziali.}
    {\parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-30pt}{
      in tutti i sistemi di riferimento.
      \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[height=2em]{example-image}
      \end{center}
    }}
    {in tutti i sistemi di riferimento non inerziali.}
    {quando gli oggetti si muovono con accelerazione costante.}
}
\end{questionnaire}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}


Images should be placed as written in my question inside {} into \question.

@Sebastiano ??? you do not say anywhere where you want the image, but the same answer applies to the first argument as the later ones, I'll add another image

Is it possible to put also into {} in \question a tikz code?

@Sebastiano yes of course tikz, includegraphics, picture mode can all be used anywhere that you can typeset text, just replace \includegraphics with \begin{tikzpicture...\end{tikzpicture} in the above
