# LuaLatex: use argument for \input, specification of lua, luatex and tex interaction

Tags: luatex, lua

I want to process command line arguments directly for usage in lua code and subsequent latex.
Looking for documentation I found no hints to tex-bindings for the `\input` command.

In this sample case I want to process multiple .tikz files by using lua.

```
%tikzmaster.tex
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \directlua{
    if not (arg == nil) then
      for i,v in pairs(arg) do
        if i == 2 then ?????.input("\string\\item[" .. i .. "])
      end
    end
  }
\end{document}
```

used with `lualatex tikzmaster.tex fig1.tikz`

So far I found [cld](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/CLD) which looks kinda unrelated and the [idea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document).
I do assume that I need to save the input-file as string for processing by tex, but I did only find output examples to print things in the lualatex [reference](http://www.pragma-ade.com/general/manuals/luatex.pdf).
May this even be conceptual impossible?

Comment: you can use the same form as in classic tex `lualatex '\def\zzz{fig1.tikz,fig2.tikz}\input tikzzmaster.tex'`  then you can iterat through `\zzz` using tex or lua as you wish.

Comment: Off-topic: .cld is for ConTeXt, not LaTeX.

Comment: I proposed a solution, but it doesn't use Lua. It doesn't make a lot of sense if you're gonna work with the command line

Comment: I've added a solution which processes your input, but it is still a mishmash of TeX and Lua. It's not impossible, but I don't see any practical advantage with respect to other methods of automated processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A first *caveat emptor*: we are supposing all relevant files are in the same directory

## First approach: use a bash script

If you're using Linux, a shell script will do the job:

### myscript.sh

Adapting the idea suggested by David Carlisle, we write the following script. Note we add the `-jobname` option so we have different output files. Otherwise, it will iterate over the same file (Sorry, I'm not fluent in Bash, so feel free to correct me if there's a better way).

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 1 $1); do 
lualatex -jobname fig$i '\def\zzz{fig'"$i"'.tikz} \input tikzmaster.tex'
done
```

### tikzmaster.tex

On the TeX side, you'll intercept the variable `\zzz` as a string and then you're gonna call the corresponding input file. Uhm, I was thinking about that and Lua doesn't do any work here

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\input \zzz
\end{document}
```

And finally, the magic:

```
sh myscript.sh 4 # 4 is an argument.
#Change according to the number of files you want to process
```

Your output files will be `fig1.pdf`, `fig2.pdf`, `fig3.pdf`, and `fig4.pdf`
So, as your files are `fig1.tikz` or `fig418.tikz`, without leading zeroes or other format variations, the script will work.

You could actually use Lua because it does nice things, but it would only replace the function of a bash script in this case.

The disadvantage of this is that it only works with files whose names follow a specific pattern.

## Second approach: actually using Lua

To emulate your example, we can do the following, using a helper `myscript.tex`

### myscript.tex

```
%!TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{shellesc}
\usepackage{luacode}
\directlua{toprocess = [[\zzz]]}
\begin{document}
\begin{luacode*}
--We capture only strings with .tikz as suffix
for w in string.gmatch(toprocess, "[^,%s]+%.tikz") do
--We remove the suffix so it doesn't appear in PDF filenames
    w = string.gsub(w, "([^,%s]+)%.tikz", "%1")
    os.execute([[lualatex -jobname ]]..w..[[ '\def\zzz{]]..w..[[.tikz} \input tikzmaster.tex']])
end
\end{luacode*}
Yay! % To avoid error messages. This actually does nothing.
\end{document}
```

Your `tikzmaster.tex` file will look like that:

### tikzmaster.tex

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{document}
\input \zzz
\end{document}
```

And your command:

```
lualatex --shell-escape '\def\zzz{fig1.tikz,fig2.tikz,one.tikz,another.tikz} \input myscript.tex'
```

Quite cumbersome, but still possible. Moreover, you can now use arbitrary `.tikz` files. There are another possibilities: you can even generate `tikzmaster.tex` via `filecontents` or read your directory content via `io.popen` to search all `.tikz` files in there, but it gets more and more troublesome. I'd opt for a bash script or another method. :)

Comment: I thought lua would make things easier, not more complicated. Sorry for your inconvenience.

Comment: No problem. It's conceptually possible, but possible not always means desirable. Entertaining, tho

Comment: Btw, Lua actually does things easier most of the time. Don't let an exception dissuade you to learn more about this fascinating language. :)