# Getting parameters from the command line to the template

Tags: templates

I would like to create a simple script (probably Python 3) to generate invoices based on *.tex template. Is there any way to change some data in this template from the command line? I mean, for example, such a simple situation that I want to run the script and give the amount for the invoice that would be inserted into it: "python generate_invoice.py --value 300$" and that 300$ will appear in a specific field in the resulting pdf file.

I couldn't find anywhere else to do that.

Comment: Why don't you just use a template engine to write `300\$` directly to the appropriate point in the latex file.

Comment: From the proposed duplicate in particular the highest voted answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1495/) instead of the accepted answer, in your case that would be something like `pdflatex "\def\amount{300} \input{invoicetemplate.tex}"` where `invoicetemplate.tex` contains a line such as `total: \amount` or something like that.