# Why latexmk doesn't include index in pdf?

Tags: pdf, indexing, latexmk

**Working command**

If I use the following command

```
latexmk -pdf -pdflatex="pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape" filename.tex
```

to compile my .tex file everything works well.

(Somewhere in the filename.tex there is something like `\newcommand{\pdfVersion}{2.0.0}`.)

**Not working command**

If I use the following command ([source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/1495/101831))

```
latexmk -pdf -pdflatex='pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape "\newcommand{\pdfVersion}{2.0.0}\input{filename}"' filename.tex
```

in the pdf the table of contents is missing (everything else looks fine).

I want to pass the latex command definition as an parameter.

(This time I try to pass `\newcommand{\pdfVersion}{2.0.0}` as a parameter.)

Comment: Probably hard to say without knowing what is in `filename.tex`. So please provide mode details that makes it easier for others to check your problem. Works just fine when I use the simplest doc I could think of.

Comment: I noticed that the problem was the command I try to pass in the script call. That's why I highly modified my question.

Comment: Again no issues here. But we really need a sample file. What is `\pdfVersion` used for. Additionally what does the log file say?

Comment: I figured out why it didn't work: I wrote `\include{filename}` instead of `\input{filename}` (actually in the question I did it right). Thank you anyway!