# variable into TEX document?

Tags: r, stata

I am trying to get a STATA macro or an R variable into Latex.
This is relatively straightforward with R markdown, but I'm hoping for a pure TeX solution.
e.g.
say I have a document that says

> Our model predicts [x] number of hamburgers will be consumed by
> aliens.

and a STATA do file or an R file that says

```
x <- 10000
```

or

```
local x 10000
```

How do I get latex to be able to update that number each time I get new data?
For figures, it's relatively simple, because I can import a code block with the figure, but what about for just numbers?

Apologies if this has been asked already--I've tried searching to no success, probably because I don't know the correct jargon and search terms to use.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can write that number to a file, say, `alien_hamburgers.txt`, and then read that file into a macro via [`catchfile`](//ctan.org/pkg/catchfile)'s `\CatchFileDef{\alienhamburgers}{alien_hamburgers.txt}{}` that you can then use in your (La)TeX file: `Our model predicts \alienhamburgers{} number of hamburgers will be consumed by aliens.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing parameters to a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document)

Comment: Thank you both for answering my question. I think the solution given by @Werner is what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write that number to a file, say, `alien_hamburgers.txt`, and then read that file into a macro via [`catchfile`](//ctan.org/pkg/catchfile)'s `\CatchFileDef{\alienhamburgers}{alien_hamburgers.txt}{}` that you can then use in your (La)TeX file:

```
Our model predicts \alienhamburgers{} number of hamburgers will be consumed by aliens.
```

---

Another option would be to write the TeX assignment into a file specifically from R, so in `alien_hamburgers.tex` would contain

```
\newcommand{\alienhamburgers}{10000}
```

that you can just `\input{alien_hamburgers}` within the preamble. This would give you access to `\alienhamburgers` within the document.

Answer (score 0):

You can include the R code to obtain the variable in the same LaTeX file, without the need of auxiliary files, as easy as in Rmarkdown. You only have to change the `.tex` extension to `.Rnw` in Rstudio (or `.Rtex` in Overleaf) to allow to the editor to know that it must be processed first by R, and then compiled to PDF by a latex engine. The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<data,echo=F>>=
x <-mean(c(500,1500)) 
@
Our model predicts \Sexpr{x} hamburgers will be consumed by aliens.
\end{document}
```