# Parsing additional command-line arguments in luatex

Tags: luatex, lua, options, command-line

I am trying to parse extra arguments given to lualatex in command line — e.g `lualatex --jobname=out in.tex myarg`.

Though I could not find it in the docs, I discovered from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18813/221452) that I can use the `arg` variable to access command line arguments. However, these give me *all* arguments given to lualatex, including options and input file.

Currently my code looks something like this:

```lua
function get_args()
    arguments = {}
    reached_doc_arguments = false
    document_arg_position = -1

    for index,argument in ipairs(arg) do
        if reached_doc_arguments then
            arguments[index - document_arg_position] = argument
        elseif argument:match("%.tex$") then
            document_arg_position = index
            reached_doc_arguments = true
        end
    end
    return arguments
end
```

However, this fails in cases where the `.tex` suffix is omited, and when options are given after the input file. I can't skip the first argument because options may be specified, and as mentioned, I can't use \jobname or status.filename.

I'm wondering if there is an intended, more complete way to do something like this?

Answer (score 3):

This is how LuaTeX parses its command line arguments:

1. If the argument contains a backslash `\`, then treat it and all further arguments as TeX code
2. If the argument starts with a dash `-`, treat it as a flag for the engine
3. If the argument is the first argument that doesn't start with a backslash or a dash, treat it as a filename (with an implicit `.tex` if not present)
4. Otherwise, ignore the argument

To capture only these final arguments that the engine ignores, you need to process the arguments the same way that the engine does. I believe that this code does what you want:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
    function get_args()
        local arguments = {}
        local filename_found = false

        for _, argument in ipairs(arg) do
            if argument:match("^%-") then -- Flags
                -- Ignore this argument
            elseif argument:match("\\") then -- Inline TeX code
                -- Ignore all following arguments
                break
            elseif not filename_found then
                filename_found = true
            else
                arguments[#arguments + 1] = argument
            end
        end

        return arguments
    end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}
    Arguments: \directlua{
        for _, argument in ipairs(get_args()) do
            tex.sprint(argument .. " ")
        end
    }
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is good, but it fails whenever a command line option takes an argument. Try to compile with (for example) ` --jobname out`. The code will print the original filename as one of the arguments.

Comment: @AtaiAmbus Ah, that's a little trickier. If you use `--jobname=out`, it works, but to make it work with a space instead of `=` you'd probably need to hardcode every option that can take an argument.