# argc argv in LaTeX

Tags: pdftex, compiling, optional-arguments, arguments

Can the LaTeX executable receive arguments from the command line to be used as internal variables?

That is, can a command like `./latex document.tex a=3 b=rational c=-17.2 d=true` be used to pass values that will be used to compile *document.tex*?

Comment: you can access the first line but easier is `latex '\def\a{3} \def\c{-17} \input{document}'`

Comment: .note. LuaTeX → [shell escape - In Luatex, how to know effective output directory? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388326/in-luatex-how-to-know-effective-output-directory/653148#comment963122_388351) and [lua - Parsing additional command-line arguments in luatex - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/650019/parsing-additional-command-line-arguments-in-luatex/650215#650215) // there's also the option of using shell-escape to `ps` to grep it but no guarantee

Answer (score 14):

The command line design for running TeX is very old, so you can find it very atypical. The command switchers (like `-ini`, `-jobname`) are read first. If next object is not `-` nor `\` then it is assumed that this is first letter of main file name. This is typical case, for example:

```
tex -ini plain.tex '\dump'
```

After file name is read, the file is read and if tex doesn't finish its job by `\end` or `\dump` primitive, then the rest of the command line is read and next input is from terminal console. Example above finishes TeX job by `\dump` given at command line.

If here is `\` instead of the "normal first letter of file name", then the command line is interpreted. Typically there can be `\def` or `\let` and, of course, `\input file`. For example

```
tex '\def\name{b} \input filename'
```

Note that there is `'...'` because we don't want to interpret the `\` by command shell.

The Unix implementations of TeX propagates its arg0 to the running program and it is converted to `-fmt arg0`. For example there is symbolic link `latex -> pdftex`. When you run

```
latex document
```

then the `pdftex` is called (due to the symbolic link) and the arg0 of the command line is propagated, so the result is:

```
pdftex -fmt latex document
```