# How to use the exact same file for handout and presentation modes in beamer

Tags: beamer, conditionals, jobname

I want to use the ***exact*** same file for my beamer presentation and handout. I do not like the need to comment out lines in order to create the handout or presentation (my current solution), nor do I want to have multiple files with an `\input` command. I realized that I can have a link (I work in linux or bsd) pointing to my main file, say

```
talk_handout.tex -> talk.tex
```

then the macro `\jobname` will let me know if I'm compiling the main file or the link. Using `\endswith` from the `xifthen` package I could then figure out if I should do handout or presentation mode.

This is all nice in theory, but in practice I have no idea how to do this. I usually have either `[handout]` or `[beamer]` in my `\documentclass` line and I don't know how to combine that with my desired use of `\jobname`.

Of course, I could have two files with an `\input` command right after the `\documentclass` line ... but I was wondering if there's another way.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think your question is answered [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2554/1235) (possible duplicate)?

Comment: I just noticed that you specifically vetoed a solution that involves `\include`. But, perhaps you could explain why this is not a good solution...

Comment: You should use `\input`, not `\include`...

Comment: see also [“Passing parameters to a document”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document/) for a variety of ways to do this (another possible duplicate?).

Comment: @Seamus: I don't like having many files "cluttering" up my directories. I don't like having to worry about setting master documents. I don't like having files that don't compile. I like the challenge.

Comment: @Henrik, @Caramdir: although the answers are closely related, the questions are different and this actually seems like the kind of question that might get asked quite often.  So I disagree with the duplicate, but agree that the three questions should be clearly connected.

Comment: @Yossi When I open a new `.tex` file emacs asks me what I want the master file to be, so that's not a problem. I have no problem with file clutter. It's not like I actually look through the folders where I store my tex documents regularly. Each file compiles (with the master document trick)...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[My answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2554/changing-latex-headers-via-a-makefile/2569#2569) to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2554/changing-latex-headers-via-a-makefile) came from exactly this situation.  The code is there, I shan't repeat that, but I'll try to explain what it does so that you can see if it's worth clicking through to that question.

My solution is exactly what you outline in your first paragraph.  I have a main file that contains all the code, say `seminar.tex`, and then a set of symlinks which all point to this file and are of the form `seminar.beamer.tex`, `seminar.handout.tex` and the same for `trans` or `article` if appropriate.  The class that I load is actually a wrapper class which looks at various parameters - both the `\jobname` and any passed to it from the document - to decide which *real* class to load (and with what options).  Thus the start of my real document is something like:

```
\documentclass[beamer,defaults]{myclass}
```

`beamer` tells it to load the beamer class, `defaults` sets up some stuff that I almost always use.  Then it looks at the `\jobname` to see what type of document it is: `beamer`, `handout`, etc, and passes the appropriate option to the `beamer` class.

For lectures, I have a further option in that the format for my symlinks is actually:

```
main_file[.type[.lecture_name]].tex
```

When I'm editing the document, I make sure that I load it via the symlink that I'm most interested in (usually the `beamer` version) and then my editor correctly compiles that version.

I used to use a method like the one Seamus outlines.  I switched to this method because:

1. When doing a lecture series, it's much easier to create a batch load of symlinks than a batch load of files with specific content.
2. If I *do* compile the master document, it falls back to something sensible.
3. It doesn't actually need all the symlinks to still work.  Since you can reset the jobname via the commandline, you could just do `pdflatex -jobname=seminar.beamer.tex seminar.tex` to get the right version compiled.

Answer (score 9):

Here's my workflow for this sort of thing. It differs quite a lot from your idea, but it achieves more or less the same goal. [edit: it differs so much that your question excludes this sort of answer. But other people looking for similar solutions might find this acceptable]

I have one file for the presentation and one for the handout. Each of them includes `\input{content}`. Then I have a third `content.tex` file that contains the actual content of the talk.

```
%%% presentation
\documentclass{beamer}
\input{content}
```

Above: the presentation; below: the handout

```
%%% handout
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\input{content}
```

But what if I accidentally compile the `content.tex`? this will break because it doesn't have a document class declaration. I use my editor of choice's multiple documents capabilities: I specify that the master document for `content.tex` is `presentation.tex`. Then compiling content actually compiles the presentation.

In emacs, this would be the content file:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
...
\end{frame}
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables: 
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "presentation.tex"
%%% End:
```

I guess I could make a makefile that runs pdflatex on both, but I don't need my handout compiled as often as my presentation: I'm often playing with overlays and compulsively recompiling to check a particular slide transition looks how I want...

Answer (score 9):

Using the idea of [Martin Scharrer's answer from a related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document/22525#22525) the following solution is quite elegant.

Assuming there is a presentation `talk.tex`:

```
$ ls talk.tex
talk.tex
$ head -1 talk.tex
\documentclass{beamer}
```

Then you can supply the `handout` class option via the command line like this:

```
$ pdflatex -jobname talk_print "\PassOptionsToClass{handout}{beamer}\input{talk}
$ pdflatex -jobname talk_print "\PassOptionsToClass{handout}{beamer}\input{talk}
```

That means that `talk_print.pdf` contains only full pages for handouts or reference.

```
$ pdflatex talk
$ pdflatex talk
```

This generates just the presentation version `talk.pdf` where the `\pause` etc. commands work as expected.

Comment: Hint: use a shell function to avoid writing the whole command, and just call something like: `pdfhandout talk`.  Using bash: add to .bash_functions the following line: `pdfhandout () {  pdflatex -jobname "${1}_print" "\PassOptionsToClass{handout}{beamer}\input{$1}"; }`

Comment: Another alternative is to use `\providecommand` as here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/614/17145

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution using `subfiles` package:

```
%% CommonBeamerMainFile.tex
%% used for ALL presentations 
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\input{praeambel.tex}  %% layout definitions
\begin{document}\end{document} %% it is basically empty
```

---

```
%% the concrete presentation
\documentclass[CommonBeamerMainFile.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
     something important here
  \end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

---

```
%% Praesentation-handouts.tex
%% create the Handout for the concrete presentation
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,landscape,border shrink=5mm]
\input{praeambel.tex}
\begin{document}
  \subfile{Praesentation.tex}
\end{document}
```

---

having this set up you can compile your presentation with
`lualatex Praesentation.tex`
and your handouts with
`lualatex Praesentation-handouts.tex`

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old post, but I wanted to share my solution too (inspired from quite a few different places). You can add this at the top of your latex file:

```
\ifdefined\ishandout
  \PassOptionsToClass{handout}{beamer}
\fi
\documentclass[... all your other options ...]{beamer}
```

Then, you can generate the handout with:

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "\def\ishandout{1} \input{yourtexfile.tex}"
```

or the regular version just as you'd do normally:

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode yourtexfile.tex
```

I extended this a bit with a script (my proficiency in `bash` is quite low, probably not optimal) to either generate a handout or a regular version without overriding the generated pdfs (basically a handout version and a regular version with `\pause` enabled, amongst other tricks I do):

```
##
## Generate latex PDF files and clear generated files
##
## Options:
##      "-b" to also generate bibtex stuff
##      "-h" to generate the handout version

texfile=$(ls *.tex | head -1)
filename=$(basename "$texfile" .tex)

gen_bibtex=""
gen_params="\input{$texfile}"
jobname="$filename"

while getopts 'bh' flag; do
  case "${flag}" in
    b) gen_bibtex="true" ;;
    h) gen_params="\def\ishandout{1} \input{$texfile}"
       jobname="$filename-handout"
      ;;
    *) printf "Wrong flag passed.\n Usage:\n\t-b to generate the bibtex\n\t-h to generate a handout\n"
       exit 1 ;;
  esac
done

printf "\n*** generate $texfile with jobname $jobname ***\n\n"
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --jobname="$jobname" "$gen_params"

if [[ $gen_bibtex == "true" ]]; then 
  if [[ $gen_params == "\input{$texfile}" ]]; then
    auxfile="$filename.aux"
  else
    auxfile="$filename-handout.aux"
  fi

  printf "\n\n*** generate bibtex $auxfile ***\n\n"
  bibtex "$auxfile"
  pdflatex --shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --jobname="$jobname" "$gen_params"
fi

pdflatex --shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --jobname="$jobname" "$gen_params"
printf "\n\n"
clear-latex-gen

printf "\n*** done ***\n"
```

The `clear-latex-gen` script (assume only one `.tex` file in directory):

```
##
## Clear latex gen files from current directory
##

texfile=$(ls *.tex | head -1)
filename=$(basename "$texfile" .tex)

printf "***remove generated files $filename ***\n"

declare -a extensions=(".log" ".dvi" ".nav" ".out" ".snm" ".vrb" ".toc" ".run.xml" ".fls" ".bbl" ".blg" ".aux" ".fdb_latexmk" "-blx.bib")

for ext in "${extensions[@]}"; do
  rm ${filename}${ext} > /dev/null 2>&1
  rm ${filename}-handout${ext} > /dev/null 2>&1
done
```