# Using the filename in the document?

Tags: tex-core, automation

I have a bunch of documents called `wk01.tex` `wk02.tex` and so on up to (eventually) 20. These are weekly handouts for a course I TA. Currently, each document starts with a `\def\classweek{5}` or whatever. I then use this in the document header. Now what I'd really like to do is have latex take the document name, do some sed-fu to strip out just the number (without its initial 0 if applicable) and then use this number in the definition of `\classweek` automatically. I've spotted reference to `\jobname` once or twice, but I'm not sure how to use that.

Is what I want to do possible?

[Are there tags appropriate for this sort of question? I couldn't think of any...]

Comment: `\jobname` expands to the file base, e.g. `wk01` for `wk01.tex`. But be careful, all non-space tokens in it have catcode 12 *"other"*, which makes comparisons a little tricky. But for numbers this shouldn't be a problem, they have catcode 12 anyway and TeX registers don't look at the catcodes.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would endeavour to only have one set-up macro to simplify the author interface. In this case

```
\myheader
```

Here is a minimal,

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\fname#1#2#3#4{%
\ifnum#3>0\gdef\classweek{#3#4}% 
\else
  \gdef\classweek{#4}%
\fi
}
\def\myheader{\expandafter\fname\jobname\classweek}
%use this to typeset the header
\myheader
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice solution! Could you explain why we need the `\expandafter` and `\fname\jobname` would be insufficient?

Comment: You need `\expandafter` because when TeX is collecting the parameters `#1`, `#2`, etc. for `\fname` it doesn't expand them, so the `#1` would become `\jobname`, instead of the w from wk02.

Comment: Nice answer!  I do pretty much the same thing with numbered quizzes.

Comment: @Yiannis could you explain the use of `\expandafter` in your answer? I think it would be good if answers on this site helped people learn about TeX and friends rather than just offered code snippets. Thanks!

Comment: @Seamus good suggestion will do it a bit later when I get a chance.

Comment: @Yiannis Ooh, also, Could you explain why you used `\gdef` rather than `\def`? This means "global definition" right?

Comment: @Yiannis one more thing: I think you should put some `%` at the end of some lines (the first line of the `\def\fname` and `\fi` lines, otherwise the `\fname` command adds spaces...

Answer (score 5):

The following depends on the file name being wkxx.tex, where each of those x's is a digit:

```
\def\getdigits#1#2#3#4{%
 \def\first{#3}%
 \def\second{#4}%
}
\expandafter\getdigits\jobname
\ifnum\first = 0\relax
  \edef\classweek{\second}%
\else
  \edef\classweek{\first\second}%
\fi
```

Comment: I think the `stringstrings` package provides a macro to get certain parts of a string. Hopefully it allows to get the last *n* characters. This way it is more robust.

Answer (score 4):

A version that doesn't require to know the name of the file, as long as it is of the form

```
<characters><two-digit number>.tex
```

So job names like `wk02.tex` or `week35.tex` would give `2` and `35` respectively:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npx \classweek
 {
  \int_eval:n { \tl_item:Nn \c_job_name_tl { -2 } \tl_item:Nn \c_job_name_tl { -1 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

In other words the macro `\classweek` will be defined as the number formed from the last two characters in the file name.

---

As of September 2015, the token list constant `\c_job_name_tl` has been removed and it has been made into a string; so the code should become

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npx \classweek
 {
  \int_eval:n { \str_item:Nn \c_sys_jobname_str { -2 } \str_item:Nn \c_sys_jobname_str { -1 } }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Answer (score 3):

This is almost exactly what I do with my lecture notes.  My code is contained in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2554/changing-latex-headers-via-a-makefile/2569#2569) to the question [Changing LaTeX headers via a makefile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2554/changing-latex-headers-via-a-makefile) and is explained in [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5899/how-to-use-the-exact-same-file-for-handout-and-presentation-modes-in-beamer/5930#5930) to [How to use the exact same file for handout and presentation modes in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5899/how-to-use-the-exact-same-file-for-handout-and-presentation-modes-in-beamer).

(I'm mainly answering here to get these questions linked together as they are similar enough that someone interested in one will find the answers to the others relevant.  In this specific case, the already-given answers are more than adequate, but someone else looking at this question might not have exactly the same set-up but still be able to figure out what to do by looking at these questions.)