# Telling LaTeX where to compile to from inside your document?

Tags: compiling, conditionals

Here is a hypothetical scenario. I want to make a beamer presentation and a handout for that presentation. I start my file as follows:

```
\newif\ifhandout
\handouttrue
\ifhandout
\PassOptionsToClass{handout}{beamer}
\fi
\documentclass{beamer}

\ifhandout
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,landscape,border shrink=5mm]
\fi
```

Now, what I'd like to add to this conditional-fu is a command that tells LaTeX to compile to `handout-\jobname.pdf` if the relevant statement is true. Is this sort of thing possible, or can I only do this from the command line?

I've not added the beamer tag because this is not a question about beamer. I couldn't think of any other tags that this might fall under.

Comment: I think that is a duplicate of [How to use the exact same file for handout and presentation modes in beamer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5899/2975).

Comment: @Martin I don't think so. I'm not asking about beamer, I'm asking about whether something is possible from within the `.tex` file. And the answers to that question don't answer my question. Indeed, I _answered_ that other question... So I don't think it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on your environment, you could try doing it the other way around: have `presentation.tex` and `presentation-handout.tex`, the latter being a symlink to the former, and inspect `\jobname` to decide. Or have a wrapper file for the handut that does a few `\RequirePackages` and `\AtBeginDocuments`, this depends a lot on how  much you need.

Comment: Could you explain how the evaluating `\jobname` thing would work?

Comment: @Seamus: This is exactly what I do for my lectures.  I explain my method in my answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5899/how-to-use-the-exact-same-file-for-handout-and-presentation-modes-in-beamer/5930#5930 (the code is actually in _another_ answer, but it's linked from that answer).

Answer (score 4):

You can't change the jobname from inside the document. (Ok, you could do some `\write18` trickery to compile the document with a different compiler instance...)

The simplest thing to do would to create a wrapper file for the handout:

```
% handout.tex
\PassOptionsToClass{handout}{beamer}
\input{presenation}
```

Where `presentation.tex` is your presentation file. Then you get `presentation.pdf` and `handout.pdf`. Note that if you use these commands on the command line the jobname will be the one of the `\input` file. You would need to use `-jobname` to change that.

Comment: On the command line, you can tell pdflatex where to compile to, right? Why can't you do that from inside the file?

Comment: @Seamus: Because the file might already be open? The PDF file isn't opened in the preamble yet, but the log file is most likely.

Comment: @Martin well I don't care where the log gets written. As long as I put it before documentclass, there's every chance the PDF file hasn't been opened yet.

Comment: @Seamus: In my tests the PDF isn't open (i.e. the old one isn't overwritten) until the first page is flushed out. But TeX doesn't care about that and fixes the `\jobname` at the beginning.

Comment: It's a shame there isn't an option to specify the jobname in the first line of the `.tex` file. That would be cool. (Although given that I'd want to put it inside a conditional, it would have to be looser than strictly the first line.)

Comment: @Seamus I think it's more a security issue than a technical problem - allowing the document to choose where the output file is written could cause possible damage when compiling a malicious input file.

Comment: MArtin your wrapper solution doesn't work as is, since like I say in my question, I want to do more with the conditional switch than _just_ pass an option to a class. I also want differentiated colour schemes for the two files...