# Conditional Compiling and \documentclass

Tags: beamer, pdftex, compiling

I am quite new to latex and don't quite get it how to compile different versions of my presentation. If this is important: I am using pdflatex and beamer.

There are three documentclasses I am currently using:

- `\documentclass{beamer}`
- `\documentclass[notes=only]{beamer}`
- `\documentclass[handout]{beamer}`

I am currently using a makefile to compile the whole stuff which basicly invokes pdflatex like this: `pdflatex  '\documentclass[notes=only]{beamer} \input{$(INPUT_FILE)}'`

Which of course means my `.tex` file is missing the documentclass and can not easily be compiled without knowledge of my Makefile. And of course thats not quite desirable ...

But how would I do better?

Comment: Some related questions: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2554/changing-latex-headers-via-a-makefile http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611/setting-class-options-after-documentclass

Comment: I'm voting to close this as a duplicate to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document. But maybe all the questions above (and the new answers to this one) can be merged into a single question?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Put the `\documentclass{beamer}` back into your main file (e.g. `presentation.tex`),  add required default options valid for all modes if there are any and execute it like that:

```
pdflatex  '\PassOptionsToClass{notes=only}{beamer} \input{presentation}'
```

This will still create `presentation.pdf` and overwrite the normal version of the PDF.

Alternatively create the following documents:

```
% notes.tex
\PassOptionsToClass{notes=only}{beamer}
\input{presentation}

% handout.tex
\PassOptionsToClass{handout}{beamer}
\input{presentation}
```

which have the benefit of creating `notes.pdf` and `handout.pdf` instead without any need for a Makefile or compiler options.

The main file can now easily be compiled simply using `pdflatex presentation` and the notes and handout with `pdflatex notes` and `pdflatex handout`, respectively.

Comment: doesn't pdflatex have an optional argument that tells you where to compile the file to? You could have a single file and use the `\PassOptionsToClass` trick but also include an output filename for each version in the makefile...

Comment: @Seamus: Yes you can use `-jobname notes` as well, but I like extra files more. Its easier if you use a Makefile but also execute `pdflatex` manually from the command line. I also got the impression that the OP want to share the files to other user which should not rely on a Makefile and command line options.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a solution that still allows easy compiling of a "basic" version. Optimally a `pdflatex beamer.tex` would be enough.

Comment: @Marcus, @Seamus: I now updated my answer to be more explicit. This way it is more clearer to people which have the same issue and find this answer using Google. I used `presentation` as example main file to distinguish it more from the `beamer` class.

Answer (score 3):

```
pdflatex '\PassOptionsToClass{notes=only}{beamer} \input{file}'
```

then your TeX file can be the default file for a presentation with the `\documentclass` line