# How do I set document options at compile time?

Tags: document-classes, build-system

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Conditional Compiling and \documentclass](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10459/conditional-compiling-and-documentclass)
>   [Passing parameters to a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document)
>   [Changing LaTeX headers via a makefile](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2554/changing-latex-headers-via-a-makefile)

I'm setting up a `Rakefile` for a LaTeX document and I'd like to be able to build different versions of the document with this script without changing the LaTeX source. The two different options that I'd like to change are:

```
\documentclass[draft]{memoir}
```

which can be changed to:

```
\documentclass[final]{memoir}
```

by invoking a different target. Is it possible to change these on-the-fly at compile time? I'm using `xelatex` if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Step 1

Create a batch file as follows, name it `batch.bat` for instance.

```
rem batch.bat takes file name without extension and the mode.
rem for example you can execute as follows.
rem batch yourtexfile final
rem or
rem batch yourtexfile draft
echo off
xelatex "\def\mode{%2}\input{%1.tex}"
acrord32 %1.pdf
```

### Step 2

Create an input file, name it `yourtexfile.tex` for instance.

```
\documentclass[\mode]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

### Step 3

Execute the batch by supplying the file name and mode as follows.

[image]

Comment: See [Conditional Compiling and \documentclass](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10459/conditional-compiling-and-documentclass), especially about `\PassOptionsToClass{..}{article}`.

Comment: You shouldn't attach pictures to show just text. Using the backticks, code blocks or `<pre> … </pre>` is _a lot_ better. Also, who said the op uses Windows and Adobe Reader?

Comment: @Andrey: [A picture is worth a thousand words](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:20090211_thousand_words-01_cropped.jpg). I let him/her adapt my example in Windows to suit his/her need.

Comment: @xport: Except of course when you are blind, on a slow internet connection, a small/bad screen or want to use copy&paste. Or when you don't want to be confused by underscores that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Hopefully no blind exploring tex.sx with a mac tiny nano connected to 1 bps line and attempting to copy/paste the contents.