# How to give arguments to a tex file during compilation?

Tags: compiling, makefile

I have a file called `main.tex`, which looks like this:

```
\begin{document}
\input{a.tex}
\end{document}
```

I want to know if it is possible to have it take this file `a.tex` in argument, such that I could compile it in a manner that depending on the argument it gives a different output automatically.

Something like `pdflatex main.tex < a.tex > a.pdf`

Comment: Does this help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24357/how-do-i-set-document-options-at-compile-time

Comment: It indeed seems close to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document. I need to take a closer look, see if I can get my answer. Thanks

Comment: Ok, it is not exactly working the same way since they seem to be working the other way around: changing the headings instead of the content. I suppose theoretically we could do it symetrically but it is not obvious to me :s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

run

```
pdflatex '\def\myfile{a.tex} \input main.tex'
```

and a `main.tex` with

```
\begin{document}
\input{\myfile}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, that was what I needed. Is there then a way such that latex gives to the output the name "a.pdf" (otherwise I will add the bash command "mv main.pdf a.pdf", but it seems less understandable than if it had the name in the first place :s)

Comment: try `-jobname=a`