# PassOptionsToClass vs global options

Tags: package-options, class-options

I'm currently using `\PassOptionsToClass`, as suggested in [Conditional Compiling and \documentclass](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10459/conditional-compiling-and-documentclass) to compile a document in several languages. However, if I use language-options in `\PassOptionsToClass`, they will not be passed to `babel`.

MWEs:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

compiles (without complaints) an empty document. But

```
\PassOptionsToClass{english}{article}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

yields

```
! Package babel Error: You haven't specified a language option.
```

since babel does not get the `english` option.

So here is my actual question:
Is there any (simple) possibility to add a global option (which is passed to subsequent packages) before the actual `\documentclass`?

Comment: What do you mean by »add a global option«? I am not sure i understand the question.

Comment: @Johannes_B with `\documentclass[<opt>]{article}` the option `<opt>` is also passed to all subsequently-loaded packages. Apparently this _doesn't_ happen when using `\PassOptionsToClass{<opt>}{article}` as shown in the example.

Comment: I think i get it, reminds me of [A class with default language settings](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/147243)

Comment: @Johannes_B Exactly. The thing is that the system isn't really set up for that, and 'hidden' language options in classes or similar are usually a tricky idea to get right.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The mechanism used by `\PassOptionsToClass` (or indeed `\PassOptionsToPackage`) targets *just* that file: it's therefore equivalent to

```
\LoadClass[<options>]{<name>}
```

and very similar to

```
\RequirePackage[<options>]{<name>}
\usepackage[<options>]{<name>}
```

In contrast, the options given as part of the `\documentclass` line are globally available to all packages and classes loaded (yes, you can have only one class using `\documentclass` but that can load a series of ones to build on). As such, the global options are stored in another place. There's no pre-defined mechanism to access this 'publicly' other than *via* the optional argument to `\documentclass`. Of course, one can access it using the internal name

```
\makeatletter
\def\@classoptionslist{english}
\makeatother
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

I'm not really sure why you would choose to do this: a class shouldn't really be messing about with this type of thing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my understanding, we have three types of options: package options, class options and global options (passed to all classes and packages). In the standard way (\documentclass[<options>]) one can set global options and with \PassOptionsToClass we can set class options. In a standard document however, one does not distinguish between class and global options.

Comment: It’s 2023. Have there been any developments towards a command like `\PassGlobalOptions` or something similar which can pass options to the class and all packages?

Comment: @Gaussler Those _are_ the options the user gives to `\documentclass`

Comment: Yes, I understand, but it would allow for a much cleaner way to make conditional global options. I would like to be able to do stuff like `\ifdanish \PassGlobalOptions{danish} \else \PassGlobalOptions{english} \fi`. As discussed in the chat yesterday, I can work around this via solutions like `\ifdanish \def\mylanguageoptions{danish}\else\def\mylanguageoptions{english}\fi \expandafter\documentclass\expandafter[\mylanguageoption,⟨other options⟩]{article}`, but this doesn’t look pretty.

Comment: @Gaussler The entire point is that global options are things the user sets

Comment: @JosephWright Yes, I get that, and that’s what I’m trying to do. I define a boolean `\ifdanish` at the top of my preamble and execute different options in my document, depending on whether I set it to true or false.