# Package writing: unset global option?

Tags: documentclass-writing

I'm writing a class file which is supposed to have a global "draft" option. However, this option is inherited by all imported packages and causes e.g. graphicx to replace all images with boxes.

Is there a way, except renaming the option, to change that? E.g. by somehow unsetting the option after it has been processed by my class?

Comment: this may be helpful http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223280/passoptionstoclass-vs-global-options

Comment: you can of course (the list of class options is just stored in a macro which you could redefine) but probably you shouldn't: the fact that all packages see all document class options is a documented feature of the latex language. It would be better to name the class option something else if it is specific to the class.

Comment: If you design a draft option, I don't see why this should conflict with `graphicx` draft -- if it is draft, then it's very convenient to drop the images as well

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Do you want to take any action here?

Comment: @Johannes_B not really but as no one else answered I'll make my comment an answer, to get it off the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can of course (the list of class options is just stored in a macro which you could redefine) but probably you shouldn't: the fact that all packages see all document class options is a documented feature of the latex language. It would be better to name the class option something else if it is specific to the class.