# Modify bibliography title independent of manager

Tags: bibliographies, documentclass-writing

I'm trying to write a custom class file, and I want to modify the style of the bibliography layout, e.g. put a blank page before the bibliography, single space it, etc. Note, I don't want to change the bib style in the sense of how the entries are formatted, just the style of the bibliography section. For the sake of clarity, let's say I want to insert a blank page before *and* after the bibliography, even though in principle I want to run arbitrary commands.

The catch is that I want to do this independent of how the user decides to create the bibliography, and I want to do it with minimal extra tex required for the user.

A simple and ugly solution would be to just define macros that the user needs to put before and after the bibliography. e.g.

```
% class.cls
\newcommand\beforebib{\newpage}
\newcommand\afterbib{\newpage}

% main.tex
\beforebib
% Create bib here e.g. \printbibliography, \bibliography{ref}, \begin{thebibliography}\end{thebibliography}
\afterbib
```

This requires creating macros in user space that then people have to remember, so I'm dissatisfied.

Another option is to case out every known type of bibliography rendering e.g.

```
% class.cls (note: this has to be called after biblatex is imported, but I've handled that)
\ifdefined\printbibliography
    \let\@oldprintbib\printbibliography
    \renewcommand\printbibliography{\newpage\@oldprintbib\newpage}
\fi
\ifdefined % etc...
```

This is what I'm currently doing, but it's error prone and not that pretty. Ideally there'd be some common macro that every bibliography package calls that I could hook into to change the styling, but finding documentation on how displaying the bibliography is actually handled has proved difficult.

Comment: That kind of tests is typical for templates. A lot of code that tries to make users life easier, but doesn't really. If you want to catch the three, or fie, or seven different ways a bibliography can start in principal, leaving the user the freedom to choose any of them, you should give them the freedom to decide if they want the start on a new page or not. This is basic [template confusion](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion/).

Comment: @Johannes_B I like your write up, and tend to agree in general, but this is a thesis template that has some strict guidelines for bibliography formatting, and this is the point of latex, to remove and strip mandatory formatting from document content. That being said, I'm modifying an existing template, and maybe it makes sense to spend more time researching modern thesis templates instead of just continually tweaking an old one.

Comment: If the guilines for bib formatting are strict, do it once and good and don't give the user any choice but to use this one thing.