# Can't specify paper size when loading scrartcl in custom class

Tags: koma-script, paper-size, documentclass-writing, class-options

By default, my system produces A4 documents. If I want to set the paper size to US Letter, I can pass the `letterpaper` option to scrartcl:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
Hello, World!
\end{document}
```

But if I create my own class that extends scrartcl, I can't pass the `letterpaper` option in the class file. E.g., this doesn't work (the resulting document has A4 paper dimensions):

#### mcve.ltx

```
\documentclass{mcve}
\begin{document}
Hello, World!
\end{document}
```

#### mcve.cls

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mcve}

\LoadClass[letterpaper]{scrartcl}
```

This *does* work if I replace `scrartcl` with `article` (although I then also have to load the geometry package in both cases to make the PDF paper size match). Even more interestingly, this also works:

#### mcve.ltx

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{mcve}
\begin{document}
Hello, World!
\end{document}
```

#### mcve.cls

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mcve}

\LoadClassWithOptions{scrartcl}
```

How can I set the `letterpaper` option in my class file?

Comment: Again? Search for papersize liadclass and typearea on rhis site.

Comment: `letterpaper` is not an option of `scrartcl` but of `typearea`. `\LoadClass` does not set  global option like `\documentclass` but a class only option. So you have to pass the option to `typearea` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As @Schweinebacke said, `letterpaper` is an option of `typearea`, not of `scrartcl`. Options passed to `\documentclass` become global options, which are propagated to all classes and packages that are loaded after the `\documentclass` declaration, whereas options passed to `\LoadClass` become local options, which are only passed to the class file being loaded, not to the packages and classes it loads.

To fix this, I needed to set the `letterpaper` option for the `typearea` package explicitly in my class file:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mcve}

\PassOptionsToPackage{letterpaper}{typearea}
\LoadClass{scrartcl}
```

More information can be found in Section 4.7 of [LaTeX2e for class and package writers](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/clsguide.pdf) and in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223280/passoptionstoclass-vs-global-options).