# When amsart is used as a base class of another class, the "fleqn" option is ignored

Tags: documentclass-writing, amsart, class-options

I tried creating my own class based on `amsart`, like this one:

```
% file: myamsart.cls
\ProvidesClass{myamsart}
\LoadClass[fleqn]{amsart}
```

However, the option `fleqn` has no effect:

```
% file: test.tex
%\documentclass[fleqn]{amsart}
\documentclass{myamsart}

\begin{document}
\[ x = x \]
\begin{equation}
  y = y
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Why does it work like this?

More generally, what is the difference between passing options with `\documentclass` and passing them with `\LoadClass`?  Is there a general method to load a base class from `cls` file with the same effect as when using `\docementclass`?

Comment: Note that the `fleqn` option in `amsart` is implemented rather strangely. The declared option does nothing.

Comment: What do you mean by "does nothing"? It works with `\documentclass[fleqn]{amsart}`.

Comment: Look in `amsart.cls` and you'll find `\DeclareOption{fleqn}{}`, but it does something "strange" with it later on in a non standard manner.

Comment: @daleif, "but it does something "strange" with it later on in a non standard manner" -- i think, i have to agree.

Comment: kindly observe that `amsart.cls` was first written before 1995, and has been used in a production capacity since then.  it wasn't designed to have options passed to it except through the option to the main `\documentclass` line, since nobody expected it to be used that way (really, that wasn't how things like this were thought of in 1995).  there are numerous classes that `\LoadClass{amsart}`; all of them that i know of expect the `fleqn` option to be specified on the `\documentclass` line.  it's too late to change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fleqn` option to `amsart` actually does nothing at `\ProcessOptions` time, because of

```
\DeclareOption{fleqn}{}%
```

The class uses a nonstandard way to set and use options. You can hack it by adding the option yourself.

```
\ProvidesClass{myamsart}
\expandafter\g@addto@macro\csname opt@myamsart.cls\endcsname{,fleqn}
\g@addto@macro\@classoptionslist{,fleqn}
\LoadClass{amsart}
```

The first `\g@addto@macro` forcibly adds `fleqn` to the list of options `myamsart.cls` is loaded with, so as to make the tests `\@ifclasswith{\@classname}` follow the “true” branch. The second `\g@addto@macro` forcibly adds `fleqn` to the global options, so also `amsmath` (and all other packages) will see and honor it.

Comment: Could you explain a bit, please, how this hack works, or at least give links or references to documentation?

Comment: @Alexey Added some explanations

Comment: @Alexey Yes, sorry for the typo

Comment: Thanks. To make your answer complete, could you add some link to an explanation of the difference between options of a class and global options? For example, [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/223283), but maybe you know better.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
\ProvidesClass{myamsart}
\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath}
\LoadClass{amsart}
```

Comment: Indeed, this has some effect, but not the same as when just using `\documentclass[fleqn]{amsart}`.

Comment: Why passing options with `\documentclass` is not equivalent to passing them with `\LoadClass`?

Comment: @Alexey documentcass options are global and seen by all packages, but if you use options to LoadClass the options are just passed to the class, so you are relying on the class to pass on the option to any packages rather than using the global option mechanism.

Comment: you can use `\LoadClassWithOptions{amsart}` and then `\documentclass[fleqn]{myamsart}`

Comment: @Herbert, it is more crazy than this.  After glancing at `amsclass` source documentation and a bit of experimenting, i observed that simply using `\documentclass[fleqn]{myamsart}` in my example makes the option have its effect.  No need to change my `myamsart.cls`, no need to pass any options to `amsart` or to use `\LoadClassWithOptions`.  This is not what i wanted and not how a class interface should work IMHO.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, is there a way to modify the global options inside the document before evoking `\LoadClass`?  (I am looking for some hackarond.)

Answer (score 0):

After being prompted by [daleif](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3929), I glanced into [amscls](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amscls) source documentation, and noticed that the actual behaviour of `fleqn` option is implemented starting with

```
\@ifclasswith{\@classname}{fleqn}{%
```

Having already experimented with different combinations of commands and options proposed by [Herbert](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2478), I decided to be bold and to simplify my `myamsart.cls` to

```
\ProvidesClass{myamsart}
\LoadClass{amsart}
```

and then to use it with

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{myamsart}
```

This produced flushed left equations exactly as when using `\documentclass[fleqn]{amsart}`.  (However, this is not what I wanted to do, because I did not want to pass any options to `myamsart`.)

Comment: IMHO, this is not how a class interface should work.