# Setting font size AFTER \documentclass

Tags: document-classes, fontsize

I've seen a few related questions, but can't find one that actually answers this question. What I want to do is to specify the font size AFTER `\documentclass`.  I don't want to change the command line, nor have to define something like `\def\pointsize{12pt}` beforehand, and then use that in the `\documentclass[\pointsize]` as per Norman's solution to [setting class options after documentclass](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611/setting-class-options-after-documentclass).  So, what I am looking for is the definition of `\SetFontSize` below so that it has the same effect as if I had said `\documentclass[12pt]{some_class}` in terms of text location and size:

```
\documentclass{some_class}
\SetFontSize{12pt}{15pt}
```

I am also not sure that 12,15 are the correct numbers to match with the `[12pt]` option. I tried the following, but this does not producing identical output as `\documentclass[12pt]{article}`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\fontsize{12pt}{15pt}\selectfont

\begin{document}
blah blah
\end{document}
```

Based on lockstep's link, I believe that the solution is:

```
  \let\savednewcommand\newcommand
  \let\newcommand\renewcommand
  \makeatletter
  \input{size12.clo}
  \makeatother
  \let\newcommand\savednewcommand
```

This seems to be working for the {article} class. But according the same link this may not work for all classes.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15835/switching-to-different-font-sizes-locally) question. BTW, your example doesn't work as expected because `\begin{document}` triggers `\normalsize`.

Comment: Note that instead of using `\def\pointsize{12pt} ... \documentclass[\pointsize]{<class>}` using `\PassOptionsToClass{12pt}{<class>} ... \documentclass{<class>}` is better. I'm aware that you try to avoid this, but just like to point it out.

Comment: @lockstep: I included the solution from the link you provided above. This seems to work, but does concern me that it may not work if I decide to switch `\documentclass` later. @Martin: I like your solution, but I have other people working with me and would prefer not to require them to adjust their software setup beyond including my header files.

Comment: So been using this solution, but found out that had to load the geometry package AFTER and not before changing the fonts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\small\relax
\let\footnotesize\relax
\let\scriptsize\relax
\let\tiny\relax
\let\large\relax
\let\Large\relax
\let\LARGE\relax
\let\huge\relax
\let\Huge\relax
\makeatletter
\input{size12.clo}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

foo

\end{document}
```

Comment: While your solution is correct for `size12.clo` (which contains `\let\Huge=\huge`), I think it is safer to add `\let\Huge\relax` to make things work for other `.clo` files.

Comment: @lockstep: yes, I'd forgotten this one

Answer (score 5):

With KOMA-Script classes it's easily possible to change the base font size after `\documentclass`, for example:

```
\KOMAoptions{fontsize=15pt}
```

Other sizes depending on the base font size will automatically be adjusted. You could use any size and any TeX unit, such as `ex`, `in` and `mm` if you like.

If you use `typearea` for calculating the layout, you could also adjust that to the new base font size by

```
\recalctypeara
```

This is just an example of many additional features which are available in KOMA classes.