# Deciding Boolean operation in LaTeX via Linux Terminal

Tags: conditionals, linux, terminal-output

How do I decide a Boolean operation in LaTeX via Linux terminal?
That is, I have:

```
%myfile.tex
\documentclass{article}

if parameter=true
is true
else
is false

\begin{document}
parameter
\end{document}
```

And I wanted to type in something like terminal

```
pdflatex -p myfile.tex #is true
```

or

```
pdflatex myfile.tex #is false
```

Comment: Not sure I understand you question, but wondering if [Norman's comment on setting class options after document class helps](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/611/setting-class-options-after-documentclass).  I have been using that solution.

Comment: Perhaps this answer [Passing parameters to a document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document/1495#1495) is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best way is outlined in [Passing parameters to a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1492/passing-parameters-to-a-document/1495#1495), which should be better known. If the document starts as

```
\ifcase\flag\relax
  <what to do when \flag=0>\or
  <what to do when \flag=1>\or
  <what to do when \flag=2>\or
  ...
  <what to do when \flag=n>\else
  <what to do otherwise>\fi
```

we are free to choose among many cases by calling the compilation through

```
pdflatex '\def\flag{<value>}\input{myfile}'
```

One can also choose a "default mode" by enclosing the above code in

```
\ifdefined\flag
   <code above>
\else
   <default setting>
\fi
```

and the call `pdflatex myfile` will compile with the `<default setting>`.

Of course the code may also be after the `\documentclass` declaration, for choosing packages at run time, for example, or different definitions of some command. I'm thinking to a "printable" version (with black colored links) as opposed to a "web" version where links are colored. But with `\ifcase` we can define as many versions as we want.

For two versions only one can use a simplified version:

```
\documentclass{article}
...
\usepackage{hyperref}
\ifdefined\coloredoutput
  \hypersetup{colorlinks,...}
\else
  \hypersetup{colorlinks=false,...}
\fi
```

and the call

```
pdflatex '\let\coloredoutput=T\input{myfile}'
```

will color the links, while

```
pdflatex myfile
```

will use no color.

Answer (score 0):

```
pdflatex '\scrollmode\newif\ifflag\flagtrue\input{myfile.tex}'
pdflatex '\scrollmode\newif\ifflag\flagfalse\input{myfile.tex}'
```

The `\scrollmode` makes TeX not to stop in case of errors. It's convenient when used in a Makefile but you could omit it if you are calling `pdflatex` from the command line.

Inside `myfile.tex` you can use `\ifflag .. \else .. \fi` to process your document depending on the value of the flag.